# Able to run java program from IntelliJ but not from command line

Tags: java

I am working on a project. I am able to run the program from within IntelliJ but when I try to run it using

```
java -cp <my jar> <Main class>
```

I get a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/nocrala/tools/gis/data/esri/shapefile/ValidationPreferences
    at Converter2.parse(Converter2.java:26)
    at Main.main(Main.java:19)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.nocrala.tools.gis.data.esri.shapefile.ValidationPreferences
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I guess because of intelleJ serve root to compiled class and does not have problem finding packages, files or class. Can you take snap shot of your project from intelleJ and post it in your question, it might give help figure out answering you correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a `jar xf` on my `jar` file and it only showed me `.classes` for the `.java` files that I had written. That gave me a hint. Basically `mvn package` did not package the dependencies into the `jar` file. I searched a bit and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1729094/147530) link on how to package dependencies into `jar`. I edited my `pom.xml` and pasted following code in it (directly taken from the aforementioned link)

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <!-- any other plugins -->
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

now when I ran `mvn package` it generated a `foo-jar-with-dependencies.jar` and I was able to execute it successfully from the command line using `java -cp ...`. I also did `jar xf` on it and verified it now contained all my dependencies. The difference in file size was also enormous as I was pulling in lot of third party packages in my project.

Answer (score 0):

May I ask what is your exact `<Main class>`? Also how did you pack the jar? Maybe you didn't include all the dependency jar libraries? (maybe in this case nocrala)?

It looks like Main.main() is already executing.

Comment: Main.main() is my main class and you can see that is was executing. I have tried packing the jar using both intellij and mvn package. Neither complains. i have included all the dependencies otherwise mvn package would have failed with an error.