# How to create a JAR Package including few dependencies in and few out

Tags: maven, jar, maven-plugin, executable-jar, packaging

I have a project where i have added few dependencies.

Now I want to create a MVN build [Jar/Package] where I want to include few dependencies in my built jar and exclude few from my build jar.

Could you someone please guide me how I can do this.

Comment: You can probably achieve what you want by declaring the "excluded" jars as provided.

Comment: Hi @JFMeier, Sorry but I am new and doing it first time. So it would be really helpful if you could explain here step by step. Like doing from crash.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Including dependencies in a jar with Maven](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729054/including-dependencies-in-a-jar-with-maven)

Comment: Hi @asettouf, You suggested thread is only about the including dependencies. I also wish few dependencies to be excluded.

So it would be helpful if you could place the example which covers the both include and exclude.

Comment: There is this example that might help: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/single/including-and-excluding-artifacts.html