# after packaging and running app I get java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, jdbc, hive

When I try to run the code in IDEA I don't get this error, but after I package it and try to run the jar with

```
java -cp app.jar com.hive.connect.controller.RecordController
```

I get this exception.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver
```

My maven

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
      <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

My code

```
public class RecordController {
private static String driverName = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";

public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Class.forName(driverName);
    Connection con = DriverManager
                       .getConnection("jdbc:hive2://host:port/db;" +
                                        "principal=principal");
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    String tableName = "evkuzmin_testHiveDriverTable";
    stmt.execute("drop table if exists " + tableName);
    stmt.execute("create table " + tableName + " (key int, value string)");
  }
}
```

Why does this happen?

EDIT 
Full error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
        at com.hive.connect.controller.RecordController.main(RecordController.java:18)
```

Comment: You specify  `-cp app.jar`, which means that none of its dependencies are on the current classpath.

Comment: @Mark thanks for pointing it out. checked how to make jar with dependencies here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729054/including-dependencies-in-a-jar-with-maven

Comment: And that can be a very brittle approach, especially with resources that might exist in multiple dependencies (eg service provider definitions); you might want to include the full stacktrace of the `ClassNotFoundException`

Comment: @Mark Brittle how? Added full error.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" -cp  "%~dp0\hive-jdbc.jar;%~dp0\app.jar" com.hive.connect.controller.RecordController
```

instead of this:

```
java -cp app.jar com.hive.connect.controller.RecordController
```

The error is due to the non-availability of the Hive JDBC jar while trying to run your Java code (which inturn tries to load the Hive JDBC jar)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

**1-if you are using maven , you have to add this in pom.xml file**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
    <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```

**2.Alternatively you can download above mentioned jar.**

- Place the jar in to hive/install location/of/lib directory...

This properly working always.

Comment: I have hive-jdbc dependency.