# ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Logger

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have an issue with maven. I wrote a java code which is running in my idea. Then i use mvn package in order to build a jar. Still no problems. But for somes reasons i don't understand when i try to execute the jar maven have created i have this error :

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
    at infra.Main.main(Main.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Logger
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
```

Can someone help a newbie like me?

Here is the beginning of java code:

```
package infra;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Proxy;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    private static String companyName = "lolilol";

    private static String baseUrl = "https://" + companyName + ".inspirecloud.net";

    private static String loginApi =  "/api/publish/Users/Login";

    private static String loginUrl =  baseUrl + loginApi;

    private static String fetchBatchesApi = "/api/query/Messenger/ListBatchesQueryByUploadTime";

    private static String fetchBatchesUrl = baseUrl + fetchBatchesApi;

    private static String detailBatcheApi = "/api/query/Messenger/ReportQuery";

    private static String detailBatcheUrl = baseUrl + detailBatcheApi;

    private static Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("proxy.local.fr", 8080));

    private static int nbEssais = 4;

    private static String header = "nbClic;Email;Id;Name;Customer;CompanyName;LastUploadTime;Type;MessageType;EmailId;ToEmailAdr;SendindState;Delivered;DeliveryError;FirstView;LastView;ViewCount;Unsubscribe;ServiceUsed;CustomerId;UrlLandingPage;GMC1;GMC2;GMC3;GMC4;GMC5;\n";

     private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Main.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        logger.info("Début des logs");

        HttpsURLConnection loginCon = null;
        HttpsURLConnection fetchBatchCon = null;
        HttpsURLConnection detailBatchCon;

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        Scanner ficIn = null;

        int retry;

        String email;
        String password;
        String type;
        String from;
        String to;


        String cookie = null;
        String lineIn;
        String[] params;
        ArrayList<String> messagesMail = new ArrayList<String>();


        // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {
                new X509TrustManager() {
                    public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                        return new X509Certificate[0];
                    }
                    public void checkClientTrusted(
                            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                    }
                    public void checkServerTrusted(
                            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                    }
                }
        };

        try
        {
            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");

            sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            logger.error("Problème sécurité");
        }
```

And then here is the POM.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>trackingGMC</groupId>
<artifactId>TrackingGMC</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>infra.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

</project>
```

If you need more informations be free to ask. Thanks all.

Comment: How do you _execute_ your jar, are you specifying the classpath of your libraries when running?

Comment: I tried to execute the jar with two differents way. First i just double click on it, but nothing happen. Then i use the command java -jar nameofmyjar.jar in a bat file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include the interested dependencies in your jar. Take a look to this [Including dependencies in a jar with Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729054/including-dependencies-in-a-jar-with-maven) or this [How can I create an executable JAR with dependencies using Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven)

Answer (score 0):

Copy the log4j jar into your Tomcat Lib folder, which worked for me