# How to add a dependency into a jar file in java

Tags: java, maven

I have an application that is packaged as jar file by maven tools. There is a dependency in the Pom.xml. It is built by `clean package` command.
When I want to run the application by `java -cp target/app.jar; org.impl.MainClass` the following exception is raised.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   freemarker/template/Configuration
>           at org.baharan.migrationXmlToAnnotation.impl.MainClass.generateTemplate(MainClass.java:80)
>           at org.baharan.migrationXmlToAnnotation.impl.MainClass.processHbm(MainClass.java:149)
>           at org.baharan.migrationXmlToAnnotation.impl.MainClass.getAllHbmFile(MainClass.java:161)
>           at org.baharan.migrationXmlToAnnotation.impl.MainClass.getAllHbmFile(MainClass.java:166)
>           at org.baharan.migrationXmlToAnnotation.impl.MainClass.getAllHbmFile(MainClass.java:166)
>           at org.baharan.migrationXmlToAnnotation.impl.MainClass.start(MainClass.java:172)
>           at org.baharan.migrationXmlToAnnotation.impl.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:183)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   freemarker.template.Configuration
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)

How is it fixed?

EDIT1:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>FreeMarker</groupId>
    <artifactId>FreeMarker</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>FreeMarker</name>
    <description>FreeMarker</description>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.23</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>convertorXmlToAnnotation</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Your app is probably only built by Maven, not packaged. Please show your pom.xml

Comment: Be sure I edit the post

Comment: I added the pom.xml

Comment: Your dependencies are only used during compile phase. You might want to add your dependencies into your Manifest file https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/classpath.html. Other option is this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729054/including-dependencies-in-a-jar-with-maven

Comment: The problem is that your jar file does not contain all dependencies which is by default. You can create a so called ueber jar which can be done by using maven-assembly-plugin or via maven-shade-plugin...

Comment: Dear Matt It is worked correctly. Thanks so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Libs are not part of a Jar. You can use the maven assembly plugin to create a "fat-jar".

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>make-assembly</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Description: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html