# builded maven's jar dosn't work

Tags: java, maven, javafx

I'm new in JavaFX. I created JavaFX project with maven and I add all dependecies. Project in idea works perfectly but when I build it in maven and try to open in target folder jar dosn't react and it gives following errors.

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
>           at sample.JdbcPlainTest.createConnection(JdbcPlainTest.java:21)
>           at sample.JdbcPlainTest.ProductsSelectQuery(JdbcPlainTest.java:84)
>           at sample.Controller.initialize(Controller.java:84)
>           at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
>           at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
>           at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
>           at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
>           at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
>           at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
>           at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
>           at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
>           at sample.Main.start(Main.java:14)
>           at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$153
>   (Unknown Source)
>           at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$51/881058039.run(Unkn
>   own Source)
>           at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$166(Unknown 
>   Source)
>           at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$45/584634336.run(Unkn
>   own Source)
>           at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$164(Unknown Sourc
>   e)
>           at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/474818150.run(Unkn
>   own Source)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$165(Unknown S
>   ource)
>           at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$46/501263526.run(Unkn
>   own Source)
>           at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
>           at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
>           at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(Unknown Source)
>           at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/96639997.run(Unknown S
>   ource)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Exception in Application start method java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unk
>   nown Source)
>           at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Sou
>   rce)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start
>   method
>           at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown So
>   urce)
>           at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$147(
>   Unknown Source)
>           at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$48/815033865.run(Unkn
>   own Source)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException:
>   file:/D:/work%20proyeqt%20immidetely/JASMIN/Qassa%20-%20CopyWORKING/target/Qassa
>   Copy-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/sample.fxml
>
> ```
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(Unknown Source)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
>     at sample.Main.start(Main.java:14)
>     at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$153
> ```
>
> (Unknown Source)
>           at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$51/881058039.run(Unkn
>   own Source)
>           at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$166(Unknown 
>   Source)
>           at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$45/584634336.run(Unkn
>   own Source)
>           at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$164(Unknown Sourc
>   e)
>           at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/474818150.run(Unkn
>   own Source)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$165(Unknown S
>   ource)
>           at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$46/501263526.run(Unkn
>   own Source)
>           at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
>           at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
>           at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(Unknown Source)
>           at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/96639997.run(Unknown S
>   ource)
>           ... 1 more Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at sample.JdbcPlainTest.ProductsSelectQuery(JdbcPlainTest.java:108)
>           at sample.Controller.initialize(Controller.java:84)
>           ... 23 more Exception running application sample.Main

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver: seems you are missing a dependency for the MySQL JDBC driver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems your dependencies are not included into your jar. Open your .jar and see whether all the dependency classes (like com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver) are inside. If they are not please see, [Including dependencies in a jar with Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729054/including-dependencies-in-a-jar-with-maven).