# log4j class not found in generated jar

Tags: java, jar, log4j, classpath

I generate jar file with `maven-assembly-plugin` plugin. I use `java -jar` to execute jar. I got error message:

> log4j: WARN JmDNS or serviceInfo not found

I tried to use path to jar in `-classpath`, but got same error.

Plugin configuration:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>make-assembly</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <mainClass>test.LeanFTest</mainClass>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
            <finalName>${project.artifactId}-fatjar-${project.version}</finalName>
            <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
            <descriptors>
                <descriptor>src/main/assembly/leanft-assembly.xml</descriptor>
            </descriptors>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: @GhostCat : I missed plugin configuration, I edited question.

Comment: @GhostCat : I use command line.

Comment: @GhostCat : I am still facing issues with this jar file, but not that was the root cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, this boils down to:

- Your maven build does **not** include dependent artefacts into your JAR file. In other words: the JAR you create does *not* include the logj4 JARs. You can change that with your maven config, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729054/including-dependencies-in-a-jar-with-maven) for details.
- As your JAR doesn't contain the dependencies, all JARs you depend on **must** be in your classpath. Meaning: when you run your new JAR on the command line, *all* elements that might be required for running it **must** be present on the classpath.

Comment: Dependencies are included in this jar file, but I already tried to use path to log4j jar file in classpath.

Comment: How can they be included when the maven config your are showing isn't written to include them?

Comment: I use two plugins to generate jar. Another one is `maven-jar-plugin`. I have two jars generated, 60 KB and 16 MB, but all the jars are copied to a `lib` named folder.