# error with aws-java-sdk-s3 when passing my jar with spark-submit

Tags: maven, apache-spark, aws-java-sdk

I am running a Spark job locally. In my code, I am creating an AmazonS3 client. I am using a recent version of `aws-java-sdk` and `spark`.
When I package my code with its dependencies and pass it to Spark submit utility, I get the following error.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.builder()

I tried different online sources and could not get rid of the error.
I even tried contacting the aws support, they asked me to add it to the spark-submit --packages. I tried that, still no luck.

Comment: Why don't you use a maven-shade-plugin to package (and shadow a jar if it conflicts with provided jar in the classpath) the aws-java-sdk jar and package it with your final jar?  https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/maven/maven-shade-plugin-example/

Comment: You can package all your dependencies as shown here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729054/including-dependencies-in-a-jar-with-maven

Comment: Thank you, that resolved my S3Client issue.