# neo4j procedure depending on signed jar (mapdb)

Tags: java, maven, neo4j, uberjar

I have created a neo4j user-defined procedure. It also compiles and works in neo4j.

Recently though, I added a dependency to my procedure plugin that prevents neo4j from starting when I try to run the newly built jar. Concretely, I receive following exception at the bottom of the stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
```

The only thing I changed is to add MapDB to my dependencies. So I suspect that it depends on some signed artifact. As it turns out neo4j plugins are "uber-jars" (i.e., shaded jars) which doesn't work very well with signed dependencies.

I figured I could try to exclude MapDB from the shading by changing the scope to `provided` and additionally adding the mapdb jar to plugins folder of neo4j. So the plugins folder of neo4j now includes both `mapdb.jar` and `myprocedure.jar`.

This doesn't seem to work though: neo4j starts, but when calling my procedure I receive a `ClassNotFound` Exception.

Any ideas on how I can solve this dilemma? I really depend on something like MapDB as my graph is very large and keeping everything in my procedure in-memory regularly leads to memory exceptions.

Many thanks in advance!

---

The important part of my `pom.xml` should it help (I started off with the [procedure template](https://github.com/neo4j-examples/neo4j-procedure-template) so it still looks quite similar):

```
<dependencies>

        <!-- other dependencies that don't make a difference ... -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapdb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapdb</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.7</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
            <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-harness</artifactId>
            <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j.driver</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Neo4j Procedures require Java 8 -->
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <!-- This generates a jar-file with our procedure code,
                     plus any dependencies marked as `compile` scope.
                     This should then be deployed in the `plugins` directory
                     of each Neo4j instance in your deployment.
                     After a restart, the procedure is available for calling. -->
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, one solution that worked was to use the `maven-assembly-plugin` instead of the `maven-shade-plugin`. The assembly plugin creates a standalone jar with all dependencies without re-packaging all dependencies.

Of course, I had to remove the `<scope>provided</scope>` for mapdb so it is also included in the assembled jar.

The rest is just replacing the shade plugin with following snippet (thanks to this [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729054/including-dependencies-in-a-jar-with-maven?noredirect=1&lq=1)):

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Afterwards I received another exception which I thought was due to a wrong signature:

```
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError ...
```

Turns out this was just because I had another procedure in neo4j that uses the same dependencies as mapdb. Quick fix was to remove that procedure library.

Of course, there are also other solutions, including removing the signature, or re-signing it. However, I explicitly did not want to remove any signatures.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware that neo4j is checking any jar signatures by default. I suspect the repackaging of mapdb artifact being the culprit.

To validate that, remove the shade or assembly plugin in and build a jar that solely contains your code. Copy that jar *and* the mapdb.jar into the plugin folder and observe logs during a restart.

Comment: Yes, the repackaging was the problem. I fixed this a long time ago already, but thanks anyways!