# Minecraft plugin NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, plugins, discord, minecraft, discord-jda

I am trying to create plugin for Minecraft, so it can comunicate with Discord. I tried using JDA library for it. But when i reference it, it will throw this error:

```
[07:13:17] [Server thread/ERROR]: Error occurred while enabling MinecraftDiscordBot v1.0 (Is it up to date?)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/dv8tion/jda/api/JDABuilder
        at notURL.RedstoneExpert.MinecraftDiscordBot.Main.discordLogin(Main.java:24) ~[?:?]
        at notURL.RedstoneExpert.MinecraftDiscordBot.Main.onEnable(Main.java:14) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:263) ~[spigot-1.14.4.jar:git-Spigot-cbd1a1b-009d8af]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:352) [spigot-1.14.4.jar:git-Spigot-cbd1a1b-009d8af]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:417) [spigot-1.14.4.jar:git-Spigot-cbd1a1b-009d8af]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_14_R1.CraftServer.enablePlugin(CraftServer.java:461) [spigot-1.14.4.jar:git-Spigot-cbd1a1b-009d8af]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_14_R1.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:375) [spigot-1.14.4.jar:git-Spigot-cbd1a1b-009d8af]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_14_R1.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:449) [spigot-1.14.4.jar:git-Spigot-cbd1a1b-009d8af]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_14_R1.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:266) [spigot-1.14.4.jar:git-Spigot-cbd1a1b-009d8af]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_14_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:775) [spigot-1.14.4.jar:git-Spigot-cbd1a1b-009d8af]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_231]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDABuilder
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:135) ~[spigot-1.14.4.jar:git-Spigot-cbd1a1b-009d8af]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:81) ~[spigot-1.14.4.jar:git-Spigot-cbd1a1b-009d8af]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        ... 11 more
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Did you compile against the library but not actually bother to add it to the Minecraft instance? You do need it at runtime too.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica How to do it? I am really noob at this. (I am using eclipse to make the plugin.)

Comment: https://www.minecraftforge.net/forum/topic/37528-using-external-libraries-in-my-mod/

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I was trying it for long time, but nope.

Comment: Some cool discord user gave me this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1729094/13157141) and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, the JDA library wasn't exported with the plugin, so I used the maven assembly plugin. It is best to use intellij idea insted of eclipse, because you can easily select what dependency you want to export.