# How to create single executable jar with all dependencies and with a properties file?

Tags: java, maven, jar, properties

Used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729054/including-dependencies-in-a-jar-with-maven/1729202#1729202?newreg=b2088220bfdc490d84debfaf92ed5b2f) link to create a single jar file that executes. But I have some properties file in the project that I would like to change before running each time, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can give that property value while executing your jar file. The given value will override configured value.
Ex: Suppose you want to change the property name while executing app jar.

```
java -jar app.jar --name="Spring"
```