# Error when parsing integer from Minecraft plugin config.yml

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft

I tried adding a path for where the user could input the number of rows in the config file and I had to parse the integer since it's a string and it keeps returning an error. I think it may be an error with the instance reference.

```java
public class GUI {

    private static Main plugin;

    public GUI(Main plugin) {
        this.plugin = plugin;
    }

    public static Inventory inventory;
    public static String inventory_name;
    public static int inventory_rows = Integer.parseInt(plugin.getConfig().getString("numberOfRows")) * 9;

    public static void initialize() {
        inventory_name = Utils.chat("&lTest GUI");

        inventory = Bukkit.createInventory(null, inventory_rows);
    }

    public static Inventory GUI (Player player) {

        Inventory toReturn = Bukkit.createInventory(null, inventory_rows, inventory_name);

        Utils.createItem(inventory, "cobblestone", 1, 1, "&6&lDisplay Name", "&7First lore line", "&7Second lore line.");

        toReturn.setContents(inventory.getContents());
        return toReturn;
    }

    public static void clicked(Player player, int slot, ItemStack clicked, Inventory inventory) {
        if (clicked.getItemMeta().getDisplayName().equalsIgnoreCase(Utils.chat("&6&lDisplay Name"))) {
            player.sendMessage(Utils.chat("&7You have clicked &6&lDisplay Name."));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the console log.

```
[23:38:49] [Server thread/ERROR]: null
org.bukkit.command.CommandException: Unhandled exception executing command 'gui' in plugin TestPlugin v1.1.1
        at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:47) ~[spigot-api-1.18.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:149) ~[spigot-api-1.18.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_18_R1.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:821) ~[spigot-1.18.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3403-Spigot-f4ff00f-2e61a5f]
        at net.minecraft.server.network.PlayerConnection.a(PlayerConnection.java:1939) ~[spigot-1.18.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3403-Spigot-f4ff00f-2e61a5f]
        at net.minecraft.server.network.PlayerConnection.a(PlayerConnection.java:1778) ~[spigot-1.18.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3403-Spigot-f4ff00f-2e61a5f]
        at net.minecraft.server.network.PlayerConnection.a(PlayerConnection.java:1759) ~[spigot-1.18.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3403-Spigot-f4ff00f-2e61a5f]
        at net.minecraft.network.protocol.game.PacketPlayInChat.a(PacketPlayInChat.java:46) ~[spigot-1.18.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3403-Spigot-f4ff00f-2e61a5f]
        at net.minecraft.network.protocol.game.PacketPlayInChat.a(PacketPlayInChat.java:1) ~[spigot-1.18.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3403-Spigot-f4ff00f-2e61a5f]
        at net.minecraft.network.protocol.PlayerConnectionUtils.lambda$0(PlayerConnectionUtils.java:30) ~[spigot-1.18.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3403-Spigot-f4ff00f-2e61a5f]
        at net.minecraft.server.TickTask.run(SourceFile:18) ~[spigot-1.18.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3403-Spigot-f4ff00f-2e61a5f]
        at net.minecraft.util.thread.IAsyncTaskHandler.c(SourceFile:151) ~[spigot-1.18.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3403-Spigot-f4ff00f-2e61a5f]
        at net.minecraft.util.thread.IAsyncTaskHandlerReentrant.c(SourceFile:23) ~[spigot-1.18.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3403-Spigot-f4ff00f-2e61a5f]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.b(MinecraftServer.java:1158) ~[spigot-1.18.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3403-Spigot-f4ff00f-2e61a5f]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.c(MinecraftServer.java:1) ~[spigot-1.18.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3403-Spigot-f4ff00f-2e61a5f]
        at net.minecraft.util.thread.IAsyncTaskHandler.y(SourceFile:125) ~[spigot-1.18.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3403-Spigot-f4ff00f-2e61a5f]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.bf(MinecraftServer.java:1137) ~[spigot-1.18.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3403-Spigot-f4ff00f-2e61a5f]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.y(MinecraftServer.java:1130) ~[spigot-1.18.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3403-Spigot-f4ff00f-2e61a5f]
        at net.minecraft.util.thread.IAsyncTaskHandler.bp(SourceFile:110) ~[spigot-1.18.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3403-Spigot-f4ff00f-2e61a5f]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.x(MinecraftServer.java:1113) ~[spigot-1.18.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3403-Spigot-f4ff00f-2e61a5f]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.w(MinecraftServer.java:1038) ~[spigot-1.18.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3403-Spigot-f4ff00f-2e61a5f]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.lambda$0(MinecraftServer.java:304) ~[spigot-1.18.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3403-Spigot-f4ff00f-2e61a5f]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) [?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class io.github.efrank801.gui.GUI
        at io.github.efrank801.commands.GUICommand.onCommand(GUICommand.java:30) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:45) ~[spigot-api-1.18.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        ... 21 more
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error while trying to get value from the config. It seems you have an issue with a dependency which is `io.github.efrank801.gui`.

To fix it :

1. If it's a plugin, you should include it in your server, and add it as `depend` in your `plugin.yml` file
2. If it's just a maven/gradle dependency, you should check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1729054) that can help you.

After adding the given dep in your jar or in the server, it will run.

You can learn more about the [NoClassDefFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34413)