# Unable to initialize main class com...., Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, maven

I have built an java application that use Swing and Flatlaf as theme.

When I'm running the application through the IDE(InteliJ) it's running without any problem.
After I have built it succsesfully using the `package` command from Maven, And when I try to run it I'm receiving this error:

(I get the same result if I build it through `maven-jar-plugin:3.1.0` plugin)

```
Error: Unable to initialize main class com.Yad2AutomationWithGUI.bouncer.Main
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/formdev/flatlaf/FlatDarculaLaf
```

I have understand that it's related to the JRE and JDK that installed on the PC, So I have updated them both to the latest version and also updated the env `Path` for them.

```
C:\Users\USER>javac -version
javac 18.0.1.1

C:\Users\USER>java -version
java version "18.0.1.1" 2022-04-22
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 18.0.1.1+2-6)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 18.0.1.1+2-6, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I have imported the `Flatlaf` repository using Maven this way:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.formdev</groupId>
        <artifactId>flatlaf</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
        ....
</dependencies>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you understand what the classpath is?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, I'm sorry, I didn't understand your question.

Comment: this is very important for a java programmer to understand. I would suggest a bit of studying

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Exception Typically happens because It is not able to find .class file at runtime during program Execution. Sometimes, it also happens because Server Engine itself is corrupted in which case new server instance has to be used.

- **Fix:**

Replace the .class file manually in the deployment directory. Once .class files are found, it will run successfully. The perfect Fix for this is to write logic for autoDeployment = "true" in a Shell Script or Java class, where all classes(src and .class, target folder and other folders in webapp) are exploded and tested and validated in their directories and then autorun the webapplication to see if the webapplication works fine.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination, I can't find the .class files that belong to missing repository

Comment: For the maven jars, jars are usually found under the m2/repo directory under the user home directory. download the jars manually, and replace in above repo and rebuild using maven.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please verify if the flatlaf classes are included in the JAR file that you have built with Maven?

Edit: The comment of Thorbjørn sounds more reliable, I would recommend looking at the classpath as well.

Another option would be to build a 'fat' JAR containing all dependent classes as well. Look into the Maven Shade plugin for that.

Answer (score 1):

For my case, I needed to assemble the jar of dependency with my main jar using maven-assembly-plugin as describe in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1729094/10074233 and then using the new jar with dependencies.