# maven project java -jar : NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/MessagingException

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-mail, noclassdeffounderror

I have a java project that sends email built with maven (using Eclipse) and it works within Eclipse with no problem, but when trying to package a runnable jar, I am having an issue

```
Error: Unable to initialize main class com.my.package.MyClass
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/MessagingException
```

I have this for my dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>

    </dependency>
```

and plugins set up like so:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <archive>
      <manifest>
        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
        <mainClass>com.mypackage.MyClass</mainClass>
      </manifest>
    </archive>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.1</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>shade</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <transformers>
          <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
            <mainClass>com.mypackage.MyClass</mainClass>
            <manifestEntries>
              <Multi-Release>true</Multi-Release>
            </manifestEntries>
          </transformer>
          <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
        </transformers>
        <filters>
          <filter>
            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
            <excludes>
              <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
              <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
              <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
            </excludes>
          </filter>
        </filters>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

I can see javax.mail-1.6.2.jar in my maven dependencies, so not sure why I am unable to run the jar...is there a config option I missed?

thanks!

I searched around and tried numerous variations of the shade and jar plugins, I expected to be able to run the jar off the command line using java -jar myjar.jar. Most of the posts I found in my search recommended adding the mail jar to the classpath, but that looks like it's already done, as the jar is in the list of maven dependencies.

### Update

Have tried multiple variations, as per suggestions below. Tried the `maven-assembly-plugin` making sure to add the `<mainClass>com.etcetera.MyClass</mainClass>` tag. With those variations I got `no main manifest attribute, in myjar.jar`. I then added in the `maven-jar-plugin` plugin, also adding the main class and I'm now back to the original error.

### Update2

when I open up the archive, I see this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.8.4
Built-By: myUserName
Build-Jdk: 15
```

which appears to be missing the `Main-Class: com.javabyexamples.java.jar.HelloWorld` line

### Resolution

I resolved the issue by building the project twice in Eclipse: `clean package` and then `clean compile assembly:single`

Comment: How did you build the jar file? `mvn clean package`? What if you extract the jar file, is the MessagingException file in there?

Comment: was doing `clean install` but changed to `clean package`; same results both ways

Answer (score 0):

When building a web app, dependencies are, of course, bundled in the .WAR/.EAR.

However, by default, Maven will **not** bundle dependencies inside your .jar file. (In other words, jars will not be put inside of other jars).

Nevertheless, you can use the `jar-with-dependencies` descriptor. More details can be found on the questions below:

[Including dependencies in a jar with Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1729054/2657515)

[How can I create an executable/runnable JAR with dependencies using Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/574594/2657515)

---

Alternatively, you could add the `mail-1.6.2.jar` on the Java classpath like so:

```bash
java -jar "myjar.jar" -cp "./path/to/mail-1.6.2.jar:./path/to/other.jar"
```

It is **not** necessary to create an executable JAR. You can package a regular jar, allow Maven to generate the MANIFEST.MF, making sure to add the regular JAR to the Java classpath, and specify the class with the `main` function on the command line:

```bash
java -cp "./path/to/mail-1.6.2.jar:./path/to/other.jar:/path/to/myjar.jar" "com.mypackage.MyClass" "param1 param2 etc"
```

*Please note that [classpath separators are different](https://www.baeldung.com/java-classpath-syntax) on Linux (colon) vs Windows (semi-colon)*

Comment: Please see updates above. I tried both these but was getting a 'no main manifest attribute' error.

Comment: You will need to add a `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9689793/2657515

Comment: I feel like Maven should create and package the manifest for you, as you have `com.mypackage.MyClass` defined in there already... but that may be a topic for another question.

Comment: ... or you can skip the manifest entirely, and specify the location of the class containing the `main` function on the command line (answer updated with details)