# Add Maven Classpath

Tags: java, android, maven-2

My project requires some external libraries to build in in Eclipse. They live in /trunk/lib whereas my project is in /trunk/projectA. To get Eclipse to find the libraries on all machines we set a variable PROJECT_A_HOME.

Now I'm trying to get some builds going with maven and I can not figure out how to add that path (be it environmental variable or relative to $(basedir)) to the build. I really do not want to set up a repository for these dependencies, as I keep them in source control and want builds to continue to work in Eclipse.

I've seen talk about  but that hasn't worked for me.

Ideas ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229757/maven-add-a-dependency-to-a-jar-by-relative-path look here

Comment: Is there no way to just add a classpath variable to the build?

Comment: it would not be portable

Comment: I'm not worried about it being portable. I just want a CI server and thought Maven could do the job. I'm not a fan of having two totally different build environments when Eclipse does a great job for debug & production builds.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your static configuration files in resources/ dir. If you have your own or proprietary jars you should set a your own repository so you can download them from the repository or better yet just install them manually , here is how

http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

Answer (score 0):

Setting up a file-based repository as suggested in this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229757/maven-add-a-dependency-to-a-jar-by-relative-path) would allow to keep the libs in your version control system and work seamlessly at the Eclipse level (the libs would be treated like any other dependency). The only problem I can think of could be at the continuous integration level: a build of `projectA` would require a checkout of `trunk/lib`. Many CI tools would allow to implement this though. And if not, moving the libs under `projectA` (or another mavenized project project if you need to share them between modules) would do the trick.