# Dependencies in maven local repositories with leiningen

Tags: maven, clojure, leiningen

I am starting `lein new` project in clojure and want to use the [goose](https://github.com/jiminoc/goose) article extraction library. Unfortunately I couldn't find the jar of that library on any publicly available maven repository, so I set out to add it to a local maven repository.

In the project directory, I copied the goose jar and its `pom.xml` files and did

```
mkdir maven-repo
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=goose-2.1.6.jar -DartifactId=goose -Dversion=2.1.6 \
    -DgroupId=local -Dpackaging=jar -DlocalRepositoryPath=maven-repo -DpomFile=pom.xml
```

And added the following to `project.clj`

```
:repositories {"local" ~(str (.toURI (java.io.File. "maven-repo")))}
```

and `[local/goose "2.1.6"]` in `:dependencies`. Now when I do a `lein deps`, I get the goose-2.1.6.jar file added to lib directory, but not the dependencies of goose. They are listed in the goose's `pom.xml` file.

Is there a way I can fix this other than listing goose's dependencies in my `project.clj`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use lein-localrepo instead of the lengthy mvn command:
https://github.com/kumarshantanu/lein-localrepo

Install like this:

`lein localrepo coords target/goose-2.1.6.jar | xargs lein localrepo install`

However, that alone will not help to install the POM file in the repo. You should additionally run this:

`cp pom.xml ~/.m2/repository/goose/goose/2.1.6/goose-2.1.6.pom`

Note that in this example Goose will be installed as `groupId=goose`, `artifactId=goose`. You can override that if you wish, and probably you should.

Comment: Yes, I've seen your `lien-localrepo` project before resorting to the lengthy mvn command. I chose the mvn 'cause its just one command :). Anyway, I'll try this method too. Can you tell me if this will get the dependencies of goose when I do a `lein deps`?

Comment: Awesome. Using this method, I get the goose's dependencies in my lib directory. Could you explain a bit more what the difference is? Thanks a bunch man :)

Comment: Also, how are these local jars supposed to be versioned? All I can think of is to add them in a vendor directory and run the above localrepo commands on every system this project is cloned. Any better way?

Comment: An artifact's `pom.xml` is expected to be present as `<artifactId>-<version>.pom` in the Maven repository, that is why you copy `pom.xml` as a new name in the second command above.

Comment: Managing/versioning local JARs is subject to what works for you. If I have to do it, I would store them under one groupId (e.g. "onlylocal") and store that directory on S3 or Github private repo or wherever so that all members in my team can clone the same repository.