# How to add libraries in clojure?

Tags: clojure

Everywhere I see, it is suggested that I add `:dependencies` in `project.clj` and run `lein deps`. Where are these downloaded? What is my `CLASSPATH` and how can I add my own JARs to my clojure project?

While the answer for

> Dependencies in maven local repositories with leiningen

kind of solves my need, I am not marking it duplicate as what I am asking is much simpler (being a beginner, who does not have much experience with Java to know about Maven). I am still finding it hard to understand where clojure ends and leiningen begins.

The thing I was looking for is a way to add library like we do in most other languages (e.g. copy JAR to project directory and import in code).

Comment: Your classpath is dynamically set by Leiningen. If you're trying to set it by hand, you're Doing It Wrong.

Comment: (And where the files go depends on your Maven configuration, but by default they'll be under `~/.m2/repo`).

Comment: ...you shouldn't be needing to bother with `lein deps` either. Whenever you run any `lein compile`, or `lein repl`, or `lein uberjar`, or other target, everything appropriate and necessary will be pulled in for you.

Comment: ...as for how to add *your own* jars, the commonly accepted approach is to create your own Maven repository. This is well-documented elsewhere, including in prior Q&A here.

Comment: Perhaps this is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738664/dependencies-in-maven-local-repositories-with-leiningen ?

Comment: I don't think so, Charles. This seems like a general "what the heck are dependencies" question, where the linked one is about including a foreign library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is great question since it's not clear at all. Leiningen is often a black hole and if something isn't working it's often hard to debug.

I just recently had to do some manual scripting and leiningen does help you with finding out these things.

> Where are these downloaded?

The directory is in `$HOME/.m2`. This is Maven's: http://maven.apache.org/settings.html

> What is my classpath?

The classpath is set depending on your `:dependencies` as well as your `:source-paths` and `:resource-paths` vectors.

You can find out your classpath like this:

```
lein classpath
```

This will print a huge list depending on your configuration.

You could --for instance-- then run a script:

```
    java -cp cljs-1.7.xx.jar:scripts:$(lein with-profile +dev-cljs classpath) clojure.main scripts/cljs-build.clj dev
```

That has access to all your projects dependencies and loads them properly.

Although you could use `lein run` to achieve something similar:

```
lein with-profile +dev-cljs run -m clojure.main scripts/cljs-build.clj dev
```

> How do I add my own JARs?

See: [leiningen - how to add dependencies for local jars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404426/leiningen-how-to-add-dependencies-for-local-jars)

Answer (score 0):

Run `lein install` from your library's project dir.
Add an entry to `:dependencies` in client's `project.clj`.
Make sure the lib name/version and its reference match (eg. `[mylib "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"]`).
Hope this helps, forget about jar loc and cp for now.