# Clojure & ZeroMQ

Tags: clojure, zeromq

Can anyone tell me some working dependencies to get up and running with zeromq and clojure?

I've tried several but leiningen isn't able to fetch them:

(Could not find artifact `org.zmq:zmq:jar:2.1.0` in central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2))

```
[org.zmq/zmq "2.1.0"]
[org.zmq/jzmq "1.0.0"]
```

I have compiled `jzmq` (`/usr/local/share/java/jzmq.jar`) and added this to my `project.clj`:

```
:native-path  "/usr/local/lib"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a 2.0-SNAPSHOT [here](https://clojars.org/org.zeromq/zmq):

Lein should already have the clojars repo loaded.

Answer (score 2):

What I propose is a mixture of what's already been proposed, but for the sake of completeness and hopefully to give a final answer I give it a try.

Since the dependency is not in the online repos I would include the jar(s) in the project's directory structure itself, e.g. in the directory `repository` and keep it in the source control system as the other files of the project. It's an important part of the project and without the dependency it won't run.

In this directory I would save the jar with the help of [Maven Install plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html).

```
mvn install:install-file \
    -Dfile=/usr/local/share/java/jzmq.jar \
    -DgroupId=org.zeromq \
    -DartifactId=jzmq \
    -Dversion=2.1.0 \
    -Dpackaging=jar \
    -DlocalRepositoryPath=repository
```

When the jar file gets copied to the local repository, you define it and the dependency in `project.clj` as follows:

```
(defproject clojure-interal-repo-test "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.4.0"]
                 [org.zeromq/jzmq "2.1.0"]]
  :repositories [["zeromq-repository" {:url       "file:repository"
                                       :snapshots false
                                       :checksum  :ignore
                                       :update    :never}]])
```

Within the project, run `lein2 deps :tree` to verify its correctness.

```
$ lein2 deps :tree
Retrieving org/zeromq/jzmq/2.1.0/jzmq-2.1.0.jar (4k) from file:repository/
 [org.clojure/clojure "1.4.0"]
 [org.zeromq/jzmq "2.1.0"]
```

Please note that the `4k` above is the size of a fake file I created to test it out.

Read the document [Repeatability](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/wiki/Repeatability) in Leiningen's wiki should you need a bit more.

Comment: Thanks, I got it working in the end. The important thing seemed to be adding /usr/bin/lib to java.library.path with :jvm-opts

Answer (score 2):

The only way I could get it to work was to use jeromq.

```
[org.zeromq/jeromq "0.3.2"]
```

Jeromq is native Java.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [Maven local repository](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html), install the compiled library into your local repo, and then, add the following to your `project.clj`

```
:repositories {"local" ~(str (.toURI (java.io.File. "your_local_repository_path")))}
```

Similar question, I have answered earlier [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8411428/how-to-use-leiningen-to-develop-using-local-jars/8411478#8411478)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, ZeroMQ is not present in public repository, at least at the last time I checked (a month ago I think). So you have to install the jar manually:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/usr/local/share/java/jzmq.jar -DgroupId=org.zeromq \
-DartifactId=jzmq -Dversion=2.1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Then you can use the artifact as `[org.zeromq/jzmq "2.1.0"]` in your `project.clj`.

Comment: Still getting 
Could not find artifact org.zeromq:jzmq:jar:2.1.0 in central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)       
Could not find artifact org.zeromq:jzmq:jar:2.1.0 in clojars (https://clojars.org/repo/)
even though I see it in .m2/