# How to install a clojure library available on my machine locally so it can be accessbile to other projects?

Tags: clojure

I've built a clojure library, it's on my local machine and now I want to test as it were a third-party library as well as testing it internally by tests.

How can I install the library locally by lein the same way I can install libraries normally by `"project.clj" -> ":dependencies [[....]]"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use leiningen to develop using local jars?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8411428/how-to-use-leiningen-to-develop-using-local-jars)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lein install` should install it to your `~/.m2` directory to give you exactly what you want.

Comment: and how can I update my library later? will "lein install" overwrite it?

Comment: the normal practice is to use a `-SNAPSHOT` version when you intend to overwrite it later, so as long as you're doing that it should be fine.

Comment: and how can I update my library later? will "lein install" overwrite it?

Comment: It said "Installed jar and pom into local repo." but it doesn't exist neither in .m2 no in .m2/repository/ Why?

Comment: I've never had that problem, so I have no idea.