# Clojure, Lein, project.clj, lein

Tags: clojure, leiningen

Right now, when I run lein, it has a tendency to:

(1) kill lib/* then
(2) reinstall/download various libraries to lib/

Now, this is a problem as I tend to copy *.jars that I need into lib/, but then lein removes them.

Question: Is there a way that lein and I can come to an understanding where either
(1) lein does not kill stuff in lib/* or
(2) lein knows of another directory to search for *.jars

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of adding them to the project, add them to your local maven repo (~/.m2)
and add them as dependencies. you can get the exact syntax for adding them by running lien deps with them missing and reading the error message. it will look something like this:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> \
  -DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>
```

in general you may want to check out this [similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404426/leiningen-how-to-add-dependencies-for-local-jars)