# How do you configure proprietary dependencies for Leiningen?

Tags: clojure, leiningen, clojure-java-interop

We're working on a project that has some Clojure-Java interop. At this point we have a single class that has a variety of dependencies which we put into a user library in Eclipse for development, but of course that doesn't help when using Leiningen (2.x). Most of our dependencies are proprietary, so they aren't on a repository somewhere.

What is the easiest/right way to do this?

I've seen [leiningen - how to add dependencies for local jars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404426/leiningen-how-to-add-dependencies-for-local-jars), but it appears to be out of date?

**Update:** So I made a local maven repository for my jar following [these instructions](http://www.pgrs.net/2011/10/30/using-local-jars-with-leiningen/) and [the lein deployment docs on github](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/DEPLOY.md), and edited my project.clj file like this:

```
:dependencies [[...]
               [usc "0.1.0"]]
:repositories {"usc" "file://maven_repository"}
```

Where maven_repository is under the project directory (hence not using `file:///`). When I ran "lein deps"--I got this message:

```
Retrieving usc/usc/0.1.0/usc-0.1.0.pom from usc
Could not transfer artifact usc:usc:pom:0.1.0 from/to usc (file://maven_repository): no supported algorithms found
This could be due to a typo in :dependencies or network issues.
Could not resolve dependencies
```

What is meant by "no supported algorithms found" and how do I fix it?

**Update2:** Found the last bit of the answer [here](https://gist.github.com/stuartsierra/3062743).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add them as a dependency to your leiningen project. You can make up the names and versions.
then run lein deps and the error message when it fails to find it will give you the exact command to run so you can **install the jar to your local repo** then sould you decide to use a shared repo you can use this same process to put your dependencies there.

Answer (score 1):

@Arthur's answer is good but I figured I'd flesh it out a bit more since it leaves some details lacking.

1. Always keep in mind [Repeatability](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/wiki/Repeatability). If you don't make it so that anyone who needs access to the artifacts can get access to the artifacts in a standard way, you're asking for support hell.
2. The [documentation on deployment](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/DEPLOY.md) is a good place to go to find out everything you need to know about deploying your artifacts. Since you're in a polyglot environment you probably can't have `lein` take care of deploying all your artifacts but at least you can get your clojure specific jars up into S3 or even a file share if you like. The rest of your artifacts will have to use Maven or Ant directly to upload the artifacts to the Maven repo on the file server or S3. At my current company we are using technomancy's excellent [s3 wagon private](https://github.com/technomancy/s3-wagon-private) to great effect for hosting our closed source artifacts and [clojars](https://clojars.org/) for hosting anything that we can open-source.
3. What @Arthur is referring to is doing a `lein install`. All that does is install a copy of the current project into your local `.m2` directory so that other projects on your box can reference them. Unless you have configured your install of maven to use a shared directory for your `.m2` folder (maybe not a bad idea in your environment?), this will mean that anyone else who checks out your project *will not be able to build it*. If you wanted to go this route, you need to set the `localRepository` node in your `$M2_HOME/conf/settings.xml` to be the shared location that the rest of your team has access to. See [the docs](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

YMMV but I've found it best to use Maven rather than Leiningen when you are working with Polyglot Clojure / Java projects.

It's mainly because the Java based tools (Eclipse etc.) understand Maven projects but don't really understand Leiningen projects. It's getting slowly better with the excellent Counterclockwise Clojure plugin, but the integration still isn't quite good enough yet for an efficient IDE based workflow.

On the repository side of things, I'd suggest setting up a private shared Maven repository. You're going to need it sooner or later if you plan to manage a complex set of dependencies within your team: might as well bite the bullet and get it done now.