# How to use lein-localrepo plugin to configure local repository dependencies for Leiningen projects?

Tags: clojure, dependencies, leiningen

I have one Clojure project named *Parallel* depending on another Clojure project named *Messaging* which I have used `lein jar` command to generate the *messaging-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar* file, then I followed the instructions on the page https://github.com/kumarshantanu/lein-localrepo to try to add local jar dependencies to *Parallel* project.
Firstly, I made a directory named *lib* under the root directory of the *Parallel* project. Then, I used command `lein localrepo coords messaging-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar | xargs lein localrepo install -r lib` to install the messaging library to the local repository *lib*. Thirdly, I added the dependency to the project.clj file of the *Parallel* project as below:

```
(defproject parallel "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
                 [...]
                 [messaging "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"]]
  :plugins [[lein-localrepo "0.5.2"]]
  :repositories {"local" ~(str (.toURI (java.io.File. "lib")))})
```

Finally, however, when I run `lein deps`, I got the following errors:

```
Retrieving messaging/messaging/0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/messaging-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom from local
Could not transfer artifact messaging:messaging:pom:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT from/to local (file:/home/mixi/Workspace/Projects/clojure/parallel/lib/): no supported algorithms found
This could be due to a typo in :dependencies or network issues.
```

I couldn't figure out why. I have did some research on this issue, like [Using local jars with Leiningen](http://www.pgrs.net/2011/10/30/using-local-jars-with-leiningen/) and [How do you configure proprietary dependencies for Leiningen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763039/how-do-you-configure-proprietary-dependencies-for-leiningen), but I still couldn't find a way out.

So what's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the `groupId` to `messaging` project, run `lein install`, modify `dependencies`. 
no need `:repositories`, get files from ~/.m2 repository.

Comment: Thanks. But what if I just want to use the lein-localrepo to install local jars to a specified directory?

Comment: sorry, I am not try it.

Comment: Running `lein install` inside the depended on library, and specifying it in the other project's :dependencies section has always worked for me. I have never had to use localrepo directly.

Answer (score 0):

When you mention `:repositories` in `project.clj` it indicates the URL to download the artifacts from. To specify a local repository use `:local-repo`. See here: https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/sample.project.clj and search for `:local-repo`.