# How to use current builds of rxjava in clojure with leiningen

Tags: clojure, leiningen, rx-java

I want to use some of the latest features being built frequently at https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava in Clojure, but am having some difficulties getting Leiningen to reference the local .jar that I build. The last version of rxjava released to Clojars was 0.9.0, which I can successfully reach with the following in my projects.clj

```
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure               "1.5.1"]
             [com.netflix.rxjava/rxjava-clojure "0.9.0"]]
```

Now, I do a successful build of the current rxjava sources, which produces the following files

```
/Users/rebcabin/Documents/RxJava/language-adaptors/rxjava-clojure/build/libs/rxjava-clojure-0.9.1-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar
/Users/rebcabin/Documents/RxJava/language-adaptors/rxjava-clojure/build/libs/rxjava-clojure-0.9.1-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar
/Users/rebcabin/Documents/RxJava/language-adaptors/rxjava-clojure/build/libs/rxjava-clojure-0.9.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

In my Clojure project directory, I do the following

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file \
    -DgroupId=local \
    -DartifactId=rxjava-clojure \
    -Dversion=0.9.1-SNAPSHOT \
    -Dpackaging=jar \
    -Dfile=/Users/rebcabin/Documents/RxJava/language-adaptors/rxjava-clojure/build/libs/rxjava-clojure-0.9.1-SNAPSHOT.jar \
    -Durl=file:maven_repository
```

following the instructions given here: https://gist.github.com/stuartsierra/3062743 (see the bottom) via http://www.pgrs.net/2011/10/30/using-local-jars-with-leiningen/ and [leiningen - how to add dependencies for local jars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404426/leiningen-how-to-add-dependencies-for-local-jars).

That reports success and produces the following:

```
$ find maven_repository/
maven_repository/
maven_repository//local
maven_repository//local/rxjava-clojure
maven_repository//local/rxjava-clojure/0.9.1-SNAPSHOT
maven_repository//local/rxjava-clojure/0.9.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
maven_repository//local/rxjava-clojure/0.9.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml.md5
maven_repository//local/rxjava-clojure/0.9.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml.sha1
maven_repository//local/rxjava-clojure/0.9.1-SNAPSHOT/rxjava-clojure-0.9.1-20130628.172154-1.jar
maven_repository//local/rxjava-clojure/0.9.1-SNAPSHOT/rxjava-clojure-0.9.1-20130628.172154-1.jar.md5
maven_repository//local/rxjava-clojure/0.9.1-SNAPSHOT/rxjava-clojure-0.9.1-20130628.172154-1.jar.sha1
maven_repository//local/rxjava-clojure/0.9.1-SNAPSHOT/rxjava-clojure-0.9.1-20130628.172154-1.pom
maven_repository//local/rxjava-clojure/0.9.1-SNAPSHOT/rxjava-clojure-0.9.1-20130628.172154-1.pom.md5
maven_repository//local/rxjava-clojure/0.9.1-SNAPSHOT/rxjava-clojure-0.9.1-20130628.172154-1.pom.sha1
maven_repository//local/rxjava-clojure/maven-metadata.xml
maven_repository//local/rxjava-clojure/maven-metadata.xml.md5
maven_repository//local/rxjava-clojure/maven-metadata.xml.sha1
```

I now fix my projects.clj file to contain the following:

```
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure               "1.5.1"]
             [com.netflix.rxjava/rxjava-clojure "0.9.1"]]
:repositories {"local" ~(str (.toURI (java.io.File. "maven_repository")))}
```

but lein deps fails to find the local repo

```
$ lein deps
Could not find artifact com.netflix.rxjava:rxjava-clojure:jar:0.9.1 in central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)
Could not find artifact com.netflix.rxjava:rxjava-clojure:jar:0.9.1 in clojars (https://clojars.org/repo/)
Could not find artifact com.netflix.rxjava:rxjava-clojure:jar:0.9.1 in local (file:/Users/rebcabin/Documents/ClojureProjects/rxjava/expt1/maven_repository/)
This could be due to a typo in :dependencies or network issues.
```

The following guesses in project.clj also do not work:

```
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure               "1.5.1"]
             [com.netflix.rxjava/rxjava-clojure "0.9.1-SNAPSHOT"]]
:repositories {"local" ~(str (.toURI (java.io.File. "maven_repository")))}

:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure               "1.5.1"]
             [com.netflix.rxjava/rxjava-clojure "0.9.1--20130628.172154-1"]]
:repositories {"local" ~(str (.toURI (java.io.File. "maven_repository")))}
```

any ideas how to proceed, please & thanks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I also answered on the mailing list where you asked this)

The `groupId` in your `deploy-file` command is incorrect. It should be `com.netflix.rxjava`. Then in your `project.clj`, use `[com.netflix.rxjava/rxjava-clojure "0.9.1-SNAPSHOT"]` for your dependency. Also note that you'll need to do the same with `rxjava.core`.

Comment: This worked!  I put the exact solution in the mailing list at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rxjava/9Xn1ioP2g9s in case someone else wants to see it.

Answer (score 1):

from the rxjava project directory run

```
mvn install
```

to install the jars to your system's local maven repo.
from your Clojure project's directory add 0.9.1-SNAPSHOT as a dependency and then

```
lein deps :tree
```

and make sure you see the correct version used.

Comment: `mvn install` is complaining that there is no .pom file, even though I can clearly see it `rxjava-clojure-0.9.1-20130628.172154-1.pom` ... `mvn` says `The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/Users/rebcabin/Documents/ClojureProjects/rxjava/expt1/maven_repository/local/rxjava-clojure/0.9.1-SNAPSHOT)`, but `ls -la *.pom` finds the file above.  Clues?

Comment: run it from the directory containing the rxjava source and pom.xml. This will compile the rxjava directory, make a jar file, and copy the jar file to the local maven repo under ~/.m2/repository/ where leiningen form the clojure project can find it.

Comment: rxjava uses gradle, not maven.

Comment: ohh, sorry for that assumption