# How do I use checked-in jars with leiningen

Tags: clojure, leiningen

We have some 3rd-party jars checked-in to our project. We'd like to add them to the classpath. That's it. We don't want to set up a local maven repo (because that would break our 'check out and run' philosophy). Each developer would have to set up their own maven repo, distinct from the project.

Is there a way to do this or is this? Most of the answers I've seen say to set up a local maven which we don't want or need just to add a jar to a classpath.

Comment: have you looked at s3-wagon-private? https://github.com/technomancy/s3-wagon-private

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You will need to setup a local maven repository, but that can be a simple directory, in your project directory, that you then check in to source control. (Which will maintain your 'check out and run' policy)

As of Leiningen 2.2.0 the functionality to deploy jars is built-in with the [`lein deploy`](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/DEPLOY.md) task. So, the task has simplified from previous versions.

Create a directory inside your project called, in this example, `myrepo`. (The name is arbitrary)

Add a `:repositories` entry in your `project.clj` file with a path to the local directory you created.

```
:repositories [["localrepo1" "file:myrepo"]]
```

Deploy your free floating jar to the repo.

```
lein deploy localrepo1 com.blueant/fancypants 1.0.1 fancypants.jar
```

And, add your dependency to your project.clj `:dependencies` vector as normal.

```
:dependencies [[com.blueant/fancypants "1.0.1"]]
```

The deploy task will generate the checksums and directory structure required to to tie into the lein dependency resolution. You can verify your jar is loaded correctly with the `lein deps :tree` command.

**Note:** File paths in `:repositories` are formatted as URLs. So, `/Users/user1/Desktop` is `file:///Users/user1/Desktop`, and, a local directory within the project, `myrepo` is `file:myrepo`.

Comment: See @siphiuel’s answer here for addenda.

Comment: After doing this, I try, in my core_test.clj, `(:require [com.blueant/fancypants "1.0.1"])` and get the dreaded `could not locate fancypants__init.class` etc when I try lein test.  Advice?

Answer (score 7):

I'd like to elaborate on [@Jared314's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19498585/571168) that helped me as well.

Below is a script that automates the process of adding multiple jars from a local `lib` folder to a local repository:

```
#!/bin/sh
export LOCALREPO_USERNAME=
export LOCALREPO_PASSWORD=

for file in lib/*.jar
do
    name=$(basename "$file")
    basename=${name%.jar}

    echo "Deploying $basename"

    artifactId="local/$basename"
    lein deploy localrepo1 $artifactId 1.0 $file

    echo "[$artifactId \"1.0\"]" >> dependencies.log
done
```

The list of Leiningen dependencies that can be added to `project.clj` is stored in `dependencies.log`.

Before running the script, `:repositories` entry in `project.clj` has to be updated to allow for reading repository username and password from the environment:

```
  :repositories [["localrepo1" {:url "file:myrepo"
                                :username :env/localrepo_username
                                :password :env/localrepo_password}]]
```

This will prevent the repository password prompt from displaying when running the script.

Comment: Thanks, this solved the error `No credentials found for localrepo1(did you mean \`lein deploy clojars\`?)`

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404426/leiningen-how-to-add-dependencies-for-local-jars/2405259#2405259).

It is indeed possible, but there's a reason why `maven` and dependency management exists. If you have many dependencies changing versions creating a repo is the recommended approach.

Comment: Please note that answer is over two years old and some of its statements aren't accurate anymore.