# Using lein project with /lib doesn't work

Tags: clojure, leiningen

When using lein 2.2, trying to put jar files in /lib does not work.

I tried and it doesn't seems to work but plenty of docs out there says this way still works.

Comment: See answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19496263/how-do-i-use-checked-in-jars-with-leiningen/19496915

Comment: A little bit oldie but goldie http://www.pgrs.net/2011/10/30/using-local-jars-with-leiningen/

Comment: Please edit your OP to expand what you're trying to do exactly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lib directory functionality was removed in Leiningen v2.0, in favor of a repository ([repeatability](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/wiki/Repeatability)).

To add [free floating jars](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/wiki/Repeatability#free-floating-jars) to a project, you will need to either deploy your dependency to [Clojars](https://clojars.org/) or a Maven repository. The Maven repository can be as simple as a directory in your project folder.

Please see the answer to this question if you need the jar in a project local folder:

[How do I use checked-in jars with leiningen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19496263/how-do-i-use-checked-in-jars-with-leiningen/19496915)

Comment: Thanks! -- this is not so helpful for my project which has a dozen or more jar files. :-)
This lein plugin should work for me https://github.com/dchelimsky/lein-expand-resource-paths

Comment: Please see the following answer regarding :resource-paths which does not require a maven repo

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use maven to access a local jar file in Leiningen v2.0

Just use syntax like this in your project.clj:

```
:resource-paths [ "local-jars/*" ]
```

and then place your `*.jar` files in the `local-jars` subdirectory of your project.

Please see this blog: http://www.troyastorino.com/tidbits/lein2-local-jars