# Using the jar created with lein in other Clojure project

Tags: jar, clojure

I have a Clojure utility jar file made from lein project with `lein jar`. 
How can I use the jar file in the other lein project? I found [clojars](https://clojars.org), but I just want to use the jar file as dependencies.

Comment: There is a answer to using local *.jar files here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/33833148/1822379