# Using local jar files with emacs clojure/cider mode and REPL

Tags: emacs, clojure, classpath, leiningen, cider

I'm trying to use functions from other jar files.

#### Creation of local jar file

I downloaded sample sources from the book [Programming Clojure 2nd Ed](http://pragprog.com/titles/shcloj2/source_code), and created a jar file with `lein jar` command.

#### Use the local jar file

From the hints in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14070422/260127), I copied the jar file in `lib/` directory, then I could add 
`:resource-paths ["lib/programming-clojure-1.3.0.jar"]` in the project.clj.

#### Test in REPL

With `lein classpath` command, I could check that the jar file is in class path. 
With `lein repl`, I could use the functions in the jar file.

```
mire=> (require '[examples.introduction :as e])
nil
mire=> (take 10 examples.introduction/fibs)
(0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34)
```

#### Isses with emacs/cider

I created a t.clj source in the `src/` directory, launched emacs with `emacs src/t.clj &`, and started REPL with `M-x cider-jack-in`.

I wrote this code, and executed it with `C-x C-e`.

(ns t
      (:require '[examples/introduction :as ex]))

However, I got a message that the file is not found.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate introduction__init.class or introduction.clj on
```

classpath:

What might be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The namespace is `examples.introduction`. Also, you don't need to quote the vector inside the `ns` macro. Try:

`(ns t
  (:require [examples.introduction :as ex]))`

See some examples of use for the `ns` macro [here](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/1.2.0/clojure.core/ns).

Also, it's customary to have at least two segments in namespaces. Yours could be `mynamespace.t` for example.