# lein local install, "Could not locate A_lib/core/as.clj "

Tags: jar, clojure, classpath, leiningen

I'm trying to follow this [recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25145487/local-dependencies-in-leiningen-without-creating-a-maven-repo) to locally install a library A and use it within another project B. lein install works on A, and lein deps works on B, but at runtime, I get `Could not locate A on classpath`.

Looking into the standalone jar file, generated with `lein [ring] uberjar` I do have     `A_lib/core.clj`. But I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
Could not locate A_lib/core/as__init.class or A_lib/core/as.clj on classpath. 
Please check that namespaces with dashes use underscores in the Clojure file name., 
compiling:(B/handler.clj:1:1)
```

Why would it look for A_lib/core/as.clj instead of A_lib/core.clj?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a simple typo,

```
[ab-lib.core as ablib]
```

Instead of

```
[ab-lib.core :as ablib]
```