# Clojure access Java Interface constants

Tags: clojure, interface, jcs

I am trying to access the constants from [this file](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jcs/commons-jcs-core/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/jcs/engine/CacheConstants.html#line.27) in Clojure:

```
public interface CacheConstants
{
    /** This is the name of the config file that we will look for by default. */
    String DEFAULT_CONFIG = "/cache.ccf";

    /** Delimiter of a cache name component. This is used for hierarchical deletion */
    String NAME_COMPONENT_DELIMITER = ":";
 }
```

Clojure attempt:

```
(import '[org.apache.jcs.engine.CacheConstants])
org.apache.jcs.engine.CacheConstants/DEFAULT_CONFIG

;; clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jcs.engine.CacheConstants
```

How do I access these two values?

Comment: Can you access anything from the jar file? Perhaps that is the problem.

Comment: @AlanThompson I am able to use the caching mechanism provided by the jar otherwise, yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The following works with a local java interface:

file:  src-java/jroot/Const.java

```
package jroot;
public interface Const {
  long ANSWER = 42;
```

file: project.clj

```
(defproject clj "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  <snip>
  :java-source-paths ["src-java"]
)
```

Clojure code:

```
(ns tst.clj.core
  (:require  ...)
  (:import [jroot Const])
)

(println Const/ANSWER)

---------
Const/ANSWER => 42
```

Note the space in the `:import` vector (very important).

Also, if [the jar file is local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404426/leiningen-how-to-add-dependencies-for-local-jars) use this syntax:

```
(defproject test-project "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
:description "Blah blah blah"
...
:resource-paths ["resources/Siebel.jar" "resources/SiebelJI_enu.jar"])
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to point to a missing jar indeed. Perhaps a wrong version. I will check that and accept your answer.