# Clojure: How to Add Dependent Project (Local) to main Clojure Project

Tags: clojure, datomic

I have a segregated Project in Clojure lets Suppose these three projects are inter dependent.

1. Clojure-IO
2. Clojure-Data
3. Clojure-Calc
   [image: The dependencies of the project are as follows]

I tried to add both the project into my clojure root directory, and tried to run the same but Im getting error saying that : **Unable to resolve symbol: k in this context**

Dependecies of the projects are

> project 2 and project 3 are dependent on project 1 so I required Project 2 and project 3 in project 1

Comment: Is [datomic] relevant here?

Comment: @cfrick yes I m using datomic in data. where my datomic relevant dependency comes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you need to use `lein-checkouts`.   Here is [a detailed description](https://jakemccrary.com/blog/2012/03/28/working-on-multiple-clojure-projects-at-once/).  See also [the documentation](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/stable/doc/TUTORIAL.md#checkout-dependencies).

Basically, you make a directory named `checkouts` at the top level of your project directory (next to `project.clj`). Inside of `checkouts`, make symbolic links to the local top-level dirs for all dependency projects.

For example, I have a project `car` that depends on 2 other projects, `engine` and `wheel`.  I structure the project like so:

```
> d car/checkouts/*            
lrwxrwxrwx 1 alan alan 17 Jun  6 21:40 car/checkouts/engine -> /home/alan/engine
lrwxrwxrwx 1 alan alan 17 Jun  6 21:40 car/checkouts/wheel -> /home/alan/wheel
```

***Update 1:*** Symbolic links (aka symlinks) are created in linux using the `ln -s` command:

```
> cd car
> ln -s /home/alan/wheel
> ls -ldF wheel
lrwxrwxrwx 1 alan alan 17 Jun  6 21:40 wheel -> /home/alan/wheel
```

Now, project `car` will see any local edits to files for both `engine` and `wheel` projects (as well as its own source files, of course).

***Update 2***

For jar file dependencies, you need to use ***:resource-paths*** in your `project.clj` file.  Please see [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404426/leiningen-how-to-add-dependencies-for-local-jars) and [this example](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/sample.project.clj#L300).

Comment: In checkouts folder, I need to add a jar file or the entire project folder, I am using datomic schemas in Clojure-Data project.

if am using folder then how am I suppose to add a dependencies in project.clj

Comment: Do i have a create a flie to create a link between subproject and a main project. If yes the what would be the file extension.and how a i supposed to give a link

Comment: In Linux systems you can just create a symlink (`ln -s`).  In Windows you should use `mklink /j`.  Just create the `checkouts` dir first, and then create the links inside that directory.