# lein tries to download artifact even though it exists locally

Tags: maven, clojure, leiningen

`lein run` results in the following error:

```
Could not find artifact foo:common:jar:10.11.0 in central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)                                                                                            
Could not find artifact foo:common:jar:10.11.0 in clojars (https://clojars.org/repo/)
```

However, on my computer, the file `~/.m2/repository/foo/common/10.11.0/common-10.11.0.jar` exists. It seems like lein is trying to download the file from central and clojars, even though it already exists on my computer.

This particular jar does not exist in the maven central or clojars, it exists in a private repository, that I only have access to when I'm on a certain network. I'm not on that network right now, so it would really help if `lein` did not try to download a file that already exists on my computer.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

**Update**

I got the information that you can run `lein` in offline mode using `lein -o ...`. This resulted in the following error though:
`The repository system is offline but the artifact foo:common:jar:10.11.0 is not available in the local repository.`

Comment: Do you have just the `jar` file under `~/.m2/repository/foo/common/10.11.0` directory? Or do you have also `common-10.11.0.pom` file?

Answer (score 1):

`lein` is likely checking for updates, which it won't be able to access while you're off that network, as you had diagnosed.
Run `lein` with its `-o` option for offline mode, and it should skip the remote repo checks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. To my surprise though, I get a new error `The repository system is offline but the artifact foo:common:jar:10.11.0 is not available in the local repository.` But as I wrote in my question, the jar exists on my computer. How can I see what paths `lein` checks?

Answer (score 1):

The above sounds good. Also see the following, where you may want to bypass the whole maven jar mechanism and put the jar in `./resources` (at least temorarily):

[leiningen - how to add dependencies for local jars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404426/leiningen-how-to-add-dependencies-for-local-jars)

Note carefully the required format of the resource strings!

```
(defproject test-project "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
:description "Blah blah blah"
...
:resource-paths ["resources/Siebel.jar" "resources/SiebelJI_enu.jar"])
```

---

See also the option for doing a local maven install in another answer in that link:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -Dfile=jaad-0.8.3.jar -DartifactId=jaad -Dversion=0.8.3 -DgroupId=jaad -Dpackaging=jar -Durl=file:maven_repository
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this if the approach of Flinchbaugh doesn't work.