# Namespace in Clojure project cannot be recognized by java code in Visual Studio Code

Tags: java, clojure, visual-studio-code

I need some Java code to work with in Clojure project. Following this [page](https://hypirion.com/musings/advanced-intermixing-java-clj) to learn how to mix Clojure/Java in Leiningen. The project was running smoothly, the result is same as expected. However, when I open the project in vscode, the namespace "myproject.records.time" in Lexer.java; it cannot be recognized in vscode but it can be recognized in command line "lein do run, clean". I have already execute the command "java: clean language server workspace" in vscode, but the errors are still exist. Please comment how to fix this error in vscode?

**command line "lein do run, clean". Working successfully**

```
=> #'myproject.main/-main
({:type :error, :value "4"}
 {:type :error, :value "3"}
 {:type :error, :value "2"}
 {:type :error, :value "1"}
 {:type :error, :value "0"})
=> nil
```

**the namespace "myproject.records.time" cannot be recognized in Lexer.java with vscode**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to add [Clojure.jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/clojure/clojure/1.10.3/clojure-1.10.3.jar) to current Project.

Reference: [leiningen - how to add dependencies for local jars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404426/leiningen-how-to-add-dependencies-for-local-jars)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This is a Clojure project in Leiningen. Can we use gradle   with Leiningen?

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding, I've edit my answer, please have a try.

Comment: Thanks for your help. your suggestion which solved a part of errors. However, errors of user defined library cannot be solved. Hopefully, I can find a solution to solve the errors this page. Reading this page "https://push-language.hampshire.edu/t/calling-clojure-code-from-java/865".

Comment: Glad to know your question had been solved. Happy Coding. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Summarized procedures to solve the errors.**

1. Download the [latest stable release](https://clojure.org/community/downloads) of Clojure. Unzip it and find the file clojure-x.y.z.jar. Copy this file into your project somewhere (eg. `./lib/clojure-1.10.3.jar`). # thanks Molly Wang
2. Put the following statement into the `project.clj`.

   `:aot [myproject.records]`
3. Execute `lein uberjar` in the project directory, a jar file will be generated under the directory `./target/uberjar`

   e.g. `./target/uberjar/XXX-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`
4. In left hand side of vscode, there is a tab named `Referenced Libraries`, add these two files `clojure-1.10.3.jar` and `XXX-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` with `+`(at the right hand side of the tab `Referenced Libraries`); respectively.

[image]