# How to deploy maven artifacts if they are not present in the central repository

Tags: maven-2, jackrabbit

What would be the mechanism to deploy rar artifacts if they are not present in the repository. (e.g. I would like to deploy [jackrabbit](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/jackrabbit/2.0.0/jackrabbit-jca-2.0.0.rar) to my j2ee application, but it is not available as part of the maven repositories. Should I have to store the binary locally in SVN and use the antrun plugin to copy it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more specific answer to your question however is that Jackrabbit is available in the central repository:

http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/jackrabbit/jackrabbit-jca/2.0.0/

You can include it with:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.jackrabbit</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackrabbit-jca</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0</version>
  <type>rar</type>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip.

I have this dependency on the ejb module right now, but it's not clear on how to deploy this rar using a maven task directly to the jboss application server.

Answer (score 3):

One would typically use an enterprise repository (like [Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/)) for this. If this is not an option, have a look at this [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229757/maven-add-a-dependency-to-a-jar-by-relative-path) for a way to store dependencies in your version control system.