# How to deploy a rar file to jboss

Tags: maven-2, jackrabbit

Refer [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468028/how-to-deploy-maven-artifacts-if-they-are-not-present-in-the-central-repository) here for a reference to the original issue. What plugin should I use to deploy the [jackrabbit rar](http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/jackrabbit/jackrabbit-jca/2.0.0/) as a separate entity to the jboss installation. I tried the rar module within the maven-ear-plugin which was actually packaging this within the ear file and the [rar plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-rar-plugin/) which seems to be used for packaging a rar. Currently I am using the antrun plugin to deploy the rar file and it's associated ds.xml, is there a different plugin to automate direct deployment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried the rar module within the maven-ear-plugin which was actually packaging this within the ear file

If you want to deploy jackarabbit rar as a separate entity, then this is not what you want. And anyway, the maven-ear-plugin is for packaging, not deployment.

> and the rar plugin which seems to be used for packaging a rar

Again, this plugin is for packaging, not deployment.

> Currently I am using the antrun plugin to deploy the rar file and it's associated ds.xml

This doesn't look so bad to me.

> is there a different plugin to automate direct deployment.

I've checked [Cargo](http://cargo.codehaus.org/) but it doesn't seem to support the deployment of rar and -ds.xml files ([CARGO-261](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/CARGO-261)). So this leaves you with the maven-jboss-plugin (see the [Deploy/Undeploy Examples](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jboss-maven-plugin/examples/deploy-undeploy-examples.html)). Not tested though.

Comment: I will probably stick with the antrun option for the time being. I am using JBoss 5.x and hence not sure if I can get the deploy / undeploy tasks running in my current environment.