# Maven, how to add additional libs not available in repo

Tags: maven-2, pom.xml

I have a maven project that has a set of library dependancies that are not available via any maven repository.  How can I add those libraries to the pom? I want to do this so when I run 'mvn eclipse:eclipse' it doesnt remove those libraries from the eclipse classpath.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 3 options:

- Add your libraries to your local repository via `install:install-file` (obviously, this is not portable, you won't be able to build the project on another machine without doing the same).
- Install and run an "enterprise repository" like Nexus, Archiva, or Artifactory and add your libraries via `deploy:deploy-file`.
- Setup a file based repository as described in this [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229757/maven-add-a-dependency-to-a-jar-by-relative-path/2230464#2230464) and put your libraries in there.

Then, declare your libraries in your pom like any other dependency.

Answer (score 8):

You can declare it as a dependency with `system` scope.

```
<project>
...
 <dependencies>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>sun.jdk</groupId>
     <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
     <version>1.5.0</version>
     <scope>system</scope>
     <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
   </dependency>
 </dependencies>
 ...
</project>
```

Comment: Not recommended at all! This is a hack, system scope is not intended for this use and this as drawbacks/side effects.

Comment: I do not agree with you. The question does not specify anything about the intended use. He needs to add it so that eclipse does not remove it from the classpath.

Comment: For any serious project that may later use things like the assembly plugin, you don't want to use system scope. This is just a bad practice, I do not recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

You can include them with your project in a sub-directory (perhaps lib/).  You can also provide .bat and/or .sh files containing all the appropriate calls to the maven-install-plugin necessary for each project member (or server env) to add these jars to the local repo.

This approach allows new project members to get up & running quickly, without having to invest several hours in setting up a new public repo for your project or team.

Answer (score 0):

You can't 'add them to the pom'. You have to put them in some repo. You can put them in the local repo with the maven-install-plugin, as suggested by the error message. Or you can deploy them in a local copy of Nexus or something like it.

Answer (score 0):

recently I created a small UI Util to install libraries to you local repository.
It works the same way as `install:install-file`.

https://github.com/escv/maven-install-ui

Comment: Please include some code on how this works instead of just a link.

Comment: the is no code required because it is a small runnable UI application. The download link is : [https://github.com/escv/maven-install-ui/raw/master/maven-install-ui/dist/maven-install-ui-0.0.1-with-dependencies.jar](https://github.com/escv/maven-install-ui/raw/master/maven-install-ui/dist/maven-install-ui-0.0.1-with-dependencies.jar)