# Maven Repository With More Recent Versions?

Tags: maven-2

Is there a Maven repository with more recent versions of the jars that I need? The main repository is often behind a few minor releases... Also, how do I go about adding additional repositories in my pom.xml file?

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a Maven repository with more recent versions of the jars that I need? The main repository is often behind a few minor releases...

Since I can't read minds, I don't know :) There is no general answer, be more specific. But in a corporate environment, one would typically run a repository manager like [Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/) and deploy anything non available in public repositories (but approved) in it.

> Also, how do I go about adding additional repositories in my pom.xml file?

To add a repository for dependencies, you need to specify a `repositories` element as follows:

```
<project>
  ...
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>my-internal-site</id>
      <url>http://myserver/repo</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  ...
</project>
```

And if you want to add a repository for plugins, you need to specify a `pluginRepositories` element (its structure is similar to the above one).

#### Related questions

- [Maven, how to add additional libs not available in repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479046/maven-how-to-add-additional-libs-not-available-in-repo)

#### References

- [Introduction to Repositories](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html)
- POM Reference

  - 5.5 [Repositories](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Repositories)
  - 5.6 [Plugin Repositories](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugin_Repositories)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing precludes you from creating your own artifacts, in fact maven supports adding 3rd party jars to your local repository:

http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html