# Pick up native JNI files in Maven test (lwjgl)

Tags: java, maven-2, java-native-interface, lwjgl

I'm creating a program with LWJGL and Maven, and I'm writing unit tests for the graphical code.  My problem is getting Maven to put the native binaries on the classpath so that the tests can pick it up.  I can't get past the error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in java.library.path
```

I've gotten the binaries to unpack to target/libs/native/, but the tests won't pick them up.

Here's my pom:

```
 <project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-  4.0.0.xsd"
>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.ziroby.kata</groupId>
<artifactId>app</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <lwjgl.version>2.6</lwjgl.version>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>## Heading ##
        <id>lwjgl</id>
        <name>lwjgl</name>
        <url>http://adterrasperaspera.com/lwjgl</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jmock</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmock-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
        <artifactId>lwjgl</artifactId>
        <version>${lwjgl.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
        <artifactId>lwjgl-util</artifactId>
        <version>${lwjgl.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
        <artifactId>lwjgl-native</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lwjgl-native</artifactId>
                        <version>${lwjgl.version}</version>
                        <type>jar</type>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/libs/natives</outputDirectory>
                        <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unpack</id>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

I've tried [Maven - Add directory to classpath while executing tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324767/maven-add-directory-to-classpath-while-executing-tests) , but that seems to be talking about resources, not JNI libraries (and it didn't work).

And [Specifiy classpath for maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677574/specifiy-classpath-for-maven) is the opposite problem: Specify things that are already on the classpath.

Comment: I have a red marker over "<execution>", not supported by m2e.

How did you change that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Trouble-with-Java-Native-Libraries-td114063.html,

> the surefire plugin starts the VM and then modifies the system  properties before passing control to the junit test classes. This is  too late for the VM, which needs to have the java.library.path set up  at the time the VM is initialized.

So we need to give the path to Surefire at startup.  The following worked:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <forkMode>once</forkMode>
                <argLine>-Djava.library.path=${project.build.directory}/libs/natives/win32:${project.build.directory}/libs/natives/linux:${project.build.directory}/libs/natives/macosx:${project.build.directory}/libs/natives/solaris</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Such `argLine` works for [scalatest](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_the_scalatest_maven_plugin) as well.

Answer (score 3):

Does surefire configuration include setting java library path

For example:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <systemProperties>
        <property>
          <name>java.library.path</name>
          <value>target/lib/natives/</value>
        </property>
      </systemProperties>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, this actually sets the path too late.  But this answer led me to a google search on which I found my answer.  So I'm giving you the bounty.