# How to set JVM parameters for Junit Unit Tests?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, jvm, intellij-idea

I have some Junit unit tests that require a large amount of heap-space to run - i.e. 1G. (They test memory-intensive functionality for a webstart app that will only run with sufficient heap-space, and will be run internally on Win 7 64-bit machines - so redesigning the tests isn't a practical suggestion.)

I am developing in Intellij IDEA, so I know I can set the JVM parameters (e.g. -Xmx1024M) for the test class. However, this is only for running the whole test class - if I want to run an individual test, I have to recreate the run congfigurations for that test method.

Also, those are IDE and box specific - so if I switch boxes (I develop on multiple machines) or one of my colleagues tries to run the tests, those settings are not transferred. (Also, other IDEs like Eclipse and NetBeans are used by my colleagues.) FWIW, we're using mercurial for source code control.

For the build cycle, we're using Maven, so I know how to specify the JVM parameters for that.

So:
- I'm looking for a way of specifying the JVM parameters that will apply for the whole test class and the individual test methods; and
- I'd like to share those specification across IDEs on any machine (having picked up the code from the repository).

Comment: I doubt it's feasible. Across machines, for a given IDE, it should be feasible. But across IDEs I don't see how.

Comment: @JBNizet - I would be happy to take across machines for a given IDE (providing it's Intellij IDEA).

Answer (score 50, accepted):

In IntelliJ you can specify default settings for each run configuration. In *Run/Debug* configuration dialog (the one you use to configure heap per test) click on *Defaults* and *JUnit*. These settings will be automatically applied to each new JUnit test configuration. I guess similar setting exists for Eclipse.

However there is no simple option to transfer such settings (at least in IntelliJ) across environments. You can commit IntelliJ project files to your repository: it might work, but I do not recommend it.

You know how to set these for `maven-surefire-plugin`. Good. This is the most portable way (see Ptomli's answer for an example).

For the rest - you must remember that JUnit test cases are just a bunch of Java classes, not a standalone program. It is up to the runner (let it be a standalone JUnit runner, your IDE, `maven-surefire-plugin` to set those options. That being said there is no "portable" way to set them, so that memory settings are applied irrespective to the runner.

To give you an example: you cannot define `Xmx` parameter when developing a servlet - it is up to the container to define that. You can't say: "this servlet should always be run with `Xmx=1G`.

Comment: where is the Run/Debug configuration at?  I don't see this in preferences or the context menu when I run the test?

Comment: Note that this will NOT change existing JUnit run configurations, only ones which are created after you change the defaults. You have to change existing ones manually.

Answer (score 89):

In Maven you can configure the surefire plugin

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>
    <configuration>
        <argLine>-Xmx256M</argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

If you use Maven for builds then this configuration will be carried in the source tree and applied when tests are carried out. See the [Maven Surefire Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/) documentation.

Comment: OP says: "*For the build cycle, we're using Maven, so **I know how to specify the JVM parameters for that**.*"

Comment: Well, the *amaidment* seems to be more interested in transferring IDE settings rather than maven (which he have already set up). Never mind, we'll see.

Comment: @ptomli - can you explain how this answers my original question? If I run tests in my IDE (which we do for debugging, in addition to being part of the build cycle), how does that pick up the JVM configuration from Maven?

Comment: @amaidment surely the Maven integration for IDEA honors plugin configurations specified in the POM?

Comment: @ptomli - I always distrust comments that begin "Surely...". Intellij maven integration uses the pom plugin configuration when running tasks on the maven build cycle. Running the unit tests in the IDE is a separate process, and by default has no knowledge of the build process. To my knowledge, there is no way of connecting these - although I'm happy to be told otherwise. Is this something you have knowledge of / have done - in which case, can you share how to do it?

Comment: You can tell Maven to run a single test: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html

There's also some help for debugging "remotely" to the surefire launched JVM.
http://devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/284976

You can launch the "mvn -Dtest=... test" process via the IDE. Eclipse has helpers to make this easy to setup, using IDE variables to pick up things like the class to test, I'm sure IDEA has similar.

Comment: I'm not sure that's possible in Intellij. TBH, even if it was, I wouldn't want to use that approach, since the chances are, if I'm running the unit tests in the IDE, I want to take advantage of the IDE debugger, which I couldn't do by running a mvn test.

Comment: Actually, IntelliJ's Maven integration *does* use the Maven Surefire configuration when executing individual unit tests. Using the Maven configuration above will cause `-Xmx256M` to be passed to the Java command line when executing your unit tests directly from IntelliJ. This has just confused the heck out of me :-(

Comment: FYI: Netbeans also uses Maven Suefire to run its tests

Comment: @Kkkev IntelliJ's Maven integration is different from running an individual test in IntelliJ. The first uses a Maven run configuration (and therefore reads the argument), the second uses a JUnit, TestNG... configuration.

Comment: I can confirm that this works in Netbeans 8.2, even running a single test.

Answer (score 29):

Parameters can be set on the fly also.

```
mvn test -DargLine="-Dsystem.test.property=test"
```

See http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2010/04/entry_385.html

Answer (score 17):

According to this support question
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206165789-JUnit-default-heap-size-overridden-

the -Xmx argument for an IntelliJ junit test run will come from the maven-surefire-plugin, if it's set.

This pom.xml snippet

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>-Xmx1024m</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

seems to pass the -Xmx1024 argument to the junit test run, with IntelliJ 2016.2.4.

Comment: Ok but what about Gradle please ?

Answer (score 14):

I agree with the others who said that there is no simple way to distribute these settings.

For Eclipse: ask your colleagues to set the following:

- Windows Preferences / Java / Installed JREs:
- Select the proper JRE/JDK (or do it for all of them)
- Edit
- Default VM arguments: `-Xmx1024m`
- Finish, OK.

After that all test will run with `-Xmx1024m` but unfortunately you have set it in every Eclipse installation. Maybe you could create a custom Eclipse package which contains this setting and give it to you co-workers.

The following working process also could help: If the IDE cannot run a test the developer should check that Maven could run this test or not.

- If Maven *could run* it the cause of the failure usually is the settings of the developer's IDE. The developer should check these settings.
- If Maven also *could not run* the test the developer knows that the cause of the failure is not the IDE, so he/she could use the IDE to debug the test.

Comment: Saying the project has to build with maven is not very helpful. (We are only building with maven.) However, implicit in your suggestion is that we should only run tests as part of the maven build cycle - we often use the same tests for debugging in the IDE. (With the further benefit that once something has been debugged it is easy to keep those tests in the build cycle.)

Comment: ok - but now you're just repeating Tomasz's answer, but with Eclipse specifications...

Answer (score 2):

You can use systemPropertyVariables (java.protocol.handler.pkgs is your JVM argument name):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <systemPropertyVariables>
            <java.protocol.handler.pkgs>com.zunix.base</java.protocol.handler.pkgs>
            <log4j.configuration>log4j-core.properties</log4j.configuration>
        </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/system-properties.html

Answer (score 1):

An eclipse specific alternative limited to the java.library.path JVM parameter allows to set it for a  specific source folder rather than for  the whole jdk as proposed in another response:

1. select the source folder in which the program to start resides (usually source/test/java)
2. type alt enter to open Properties page for that folder
3. select native in the left panel
4. Edit the native path. The path can be absolute or  relative to the workspace, the second being more change resilient.

For those interested on detail on why maven argline tag should be preferred to the systemProperties one, look, for example:

[Pick up native JNI files in Maven test (lwjgl)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195234/pick-up-native-jni-files-in-maven-test-lwjgl)

Answer (score 1):

If you set it in Java code, you can set it like this

```
      static {
        System.getProperties().setProperty("env", "test");
        System.getProperties().setProperty("spring.application.name", "spring-example");
    }
```

reference：

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60654275/4712855

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10774432/4712855