# How to implement an eclipse VM argument in code

Tags: java, vlc, vlcj, run-configuration

This is probably a simple question but I'm currently working with vlcj to make a video player for a project. I have a basic player working but only when I have the VM arguement

```
-Djna.library.path="C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC"
```

defined in the debug configurations window. My question is if I need to create a version of this project to run outside of Eclipse do I need to define this argument in my code or will my program run in this way without problems indefinitely?

Thanks to anyone who answers,

Jared.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think

```
System.getProperties().setProperty("jna.library.path",
  "C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC");
```

should do the job in code for this particular case.  `-D` arguments to `java` set system properties, which end up in `System.getProperties()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set JVM arguments at runtime, if you are going to export your project you'll have to find another way to do it: this is done by wrapping the execution of your program within a script file, let it be a `.bat` or `.sh` so that you can invoke the java executable with your paramters set.

I'm assuming you are talking about executing the program outside Eclipse.

Comment: Yes I'm talking about running the program outside of eclipse. Would you be able to tell me the key words I would need to use to research information on how to implement this?

Comment: Basically we're talking about embedding jvm arguments, although there is no direct way to do it (even inside a .jar)

Comment: You can't set _general_ JVM arguments at runtime, but I wonder if you can set these. I was under the impression that `-D` arguments just went into `System.getProperties()`.