# When will Javassist 3.17.0-GA be available

Tags: powermock, javassist

Anyone know when Javassist 3.17.0-GA will be made available?

There is a bug in Javaassit (fixed in 3.17.0-GA) that is breaking PowerMock when used with Java 7:
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JASSIST-160?focusedCommentId=12718716&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-12718716

Associated PowerMock bug
http://code.google.com/p/powermock/issues/detail?id=355

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is something that should be directed at the software maintainers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It's available**. It looks like updating the version has resolved my issue which I believe would have been similar to yours. I assume your problem is some variation of [java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15122890/977087).

At the time of writing version 3.19 of Javassist is [available](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.javassist/javassist). PowerMock [1.5.1](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.powermock/powermock-core/1.5.1) is also updated to use Javassist 3.18 GA.

---

**Alternative fixes** 
Besides the upgrade, one of the other recommended solutions is the use of the JVM argument -XX:-UseSplitVerifier from a combination of [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15122890/977087) on Java 7 stack map issues and [here](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/issues/detail?id=355) on the PowerMock issues registry about java.lang.VerifyError (which you have linked to).

**Implementations Of Alternative Fixes** 
In IntelliJ I've added the -UseSplitVerifier to my JUnit runner but there are also recommendations about adding it to the Maven *Surefire* plugin in your build in order to make the solution portable such as is recommended in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7579864/977087) post.