# java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target JDK 1.7

Tags: java, jaxb, java-7

After upgrading to JDK 1.7 I am getting below exception:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 71 in method com.abc.domain.myPackage.MyClass$JaxbAccessorM_getDescription_setDescription_java_lang_String.get(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; at offset 20
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2413)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2723)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:345)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:327)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.OptimizedAccessorFactory.instanciate(OptimizedAccessorFactory.java:184)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.OptimizedAccessorFactory.get(OptimizedAccessorFactory.java:129)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Accessor$GetterSetterReflection.optimize(Accessor.java:384)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementLeafProperty.<init>(SingleElementLeafProperty.java:72)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.PropertyFactory.create(PropertyFactory.java:113)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:166)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:494)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:311)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:126)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1148)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:130)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:248)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:235)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:445)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:637)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:584)
    at com.abc.domain.myPackage.MyClass.marshalFacetsTest(MyClass.java:73)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1203)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1128)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1036)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
```

Answer (score 176):

Java 7 introduced stricter verification and changed the class format a bit—to contain a stack map used to verify that code is correct. The exception you see means that some method doesn't have a valid stack map.

Java version or bytecode instrumentation could both be to blame. Usually this means that a library used by the application generates invalid bytecode that doesn't pass the stricter verification. So nothing else than reporting it as a bug to the library can be done by the developer.

As a workaround you can add `-noverify` to the JVM arguments in order to disable verification. In Java 7 it was also possible to use `-XX:-UseSplitVerifier` to use the less strict verification method, but that option was removed in Java 8.

Comment: But what does -XX:-UseSplitVerifier mean??  I looked at oracle's explaination,It says "Use the new type checker with StackMapTable attributes". I didn't get it.

Comment: So if I see this errors: Is this a bug within the JVM or my code?

Comment: this answer is not valid in the long terms, or perhaps any longer already, as Oracle is deprecating this option. I'm afflicted by this bug (with other code) and am looking for a way to fore rebuild of stackmaps

Comment: Does anyone has an idea about what if the same situation but runs on a linux machine? I got the error that "-XX:-UseSplitVerifier: command not found".

Comment: After using UseSplitVerifier and noverify options, the byte code validation error goes away.  But then I get a new error: NoClassDefFoundError.  I am using  jdk1.7.0_76 on OS X 10.10.3.

Comment: for unit test you have to pass the arguments in the surefire plugin. This fixed the issue for both java 7 and 8 compilers:<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.18.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <argLine>-noverify -XX:-UseSplitVerifier</argLine>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

Comment: I've had exactly the same issue on Java 1.8, and the option -noverify did the work. Is there anything better to fix it?

Comment: i was facing the same issue but after adding -noverify it really worked for me.Thanks.

Comment: -noverify also worked for me.  I'm using gradle for Android and so I had to put the -noverify flag where specified in https://stackoverflow.com/a/37593189/2848676

Answer (score 16):

If you are using java 1.8, remove `XX:-UseSplitVerifier` and use `-noverify` in your JVM properties.

Answer (score 8):

I ran into this problem and try using the flag `-noverify` which really works. It is because of the new bytecode verifier. So the flag should really work.
I am using JDK 1.7.

Note: This would not work if you are using JDK 1.8

Comment: For me using the flag fixed executing our Android Unit Tests using JRE 8 as a runtime.

Comment: -noverify also worked for me on Java 8. I'm using gradle for Android and so I had to put the -noverify flag where specified in stackoverflow.com/a/37593189/2848676

Comment: where did you set -noverify? I set it as MAVEN_OPTS but its not working for me

Comment: @Sara Antunez,
In your application modules' build.gradle file in android closure, add this.

android {
  ....

  testOptions {
    unitTests.all {
      jvmArgs '-noverify'
    }
  }
}

Answer (score 4):

Pass `-noverify` JVM argument to your test task. If you are using gradle, in the `build.gradle` you can have something like:

```
test {
  jvmArgs "-noverify"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The only difference between files that causing the issue is the 8th byte of file

CA FE BA BE 00 00 00 33 - Java 7

vs.

CA FE BA BE 00 00 00 32 - Java 6

Setting `-XX:-UseSplitVerifier` resolves the issue. However, the cause of this issue is https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=339388

Answer (score 0):

This ERROR can happen when you use Mockito to **mock final classes**.

Consider using Mockito inline or Powermock instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue that was caused by the `-preverify` flag. Removing that flag fixed the issue for me. JVM 1.7+ is incompatible with that option. https://www.guardsquare.com/manual/configuration/usage#dontpreverify

Answer (score -2):

Sorry for digging, but I met the same problem and found the simplier solution.

In Java compiler options you need to uncheck **"Preserve unused (never read) local variables"** so there is no need to change back target JVM version.

It seems to be a bug in an older Eclipe versions.

Comment: it doesn't work for me. Here's a gist of my error: https://gist.github.com/ZiglioNZ/bd1d7d424727b3f26c64

Comment: The OP doesn't mention Eclipse. He may not even be using it.

Answer (score -4):

If you are building the code yourself, then this issue could be overcome by giving "-target 1.5" to the java compiler (or by setting the corresponding option in your IDE or your build config).

Answer (score -11):

this link is helpful. 
[java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8958267/java-lang-verifyerror-expecting-a-stackmap-frame)

the simplest way is changing JRE to 6.

Comment: downgrading when a simple JVM arg can fix? I doubt your definition of simple.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: This is a work around. As Joachim said, it may work - but it doesn't define the problem or help for teams or code bases that must use Java 7

Comment: There are multiple answers in the linked question.  Downgrading is only one listed option.