# Jvm options in android when run gradlew test

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, robolectric

I have a project that using Robolectric for unit test purpose. This project uses Robolectric 3.0 and need to add `-ea` and `-noverify` options in Virtual Machine options.

In Android Studio, I created new JUnit configuration in `Run > Edit Configurations...` and then set `VM Options` to `-ea -noverify`. With this way I success to run my unit test. This is image about my configure, view [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwJHrbTmyE1sS2tMWXJmaFBkSEU/view?usp=sharing)

However, for continuous deployment, I need run unit test with command line. So I use `./gradlew test` to run unit test. I also add `org.gradle.jvmargs=-ea -noverify` to `gradle.properties` file. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I can run unit test but I got `java.lang.VerifyError` and I think that `gradle.properties` was not load.

So, my question is, how to make `gradle.properties` load or do you know any way to fix my vm options problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found that we can add this block to app's build.gradle to solve this problem

```
tasks.whenTaskAdded { theTask ->
    def taskName = theTask.name.toString()
    if ("testDevDebug".toString().equals(taskName)) {
        theTask.jvmArgs('-ea', '-noverify')
    }
}
```

`DevDebug` is my build variant.

Comment: Gradle DSL method not found: 'jvmArgs()'

Answer (score 45):

It is already answered but this may be an easier solution:

In your application modules' `build.gradle` file in android closure, add this.

```
android {
  ....

  testOptions {
    unitTests.all {
      jvmArgs '-noverify'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This one is so much cleaner. "gradle way"

Comment: Has anybody had any experience getting this working with Android Studio 2.3?  I am still seeing tests crash even with this in place.

Comment: this does not work on 2.3.3. the accepted answer works great

Comment: It worked for me. I have the Android plugin v. 3.0.1

Comment: This definitely works with plugin 3.0.1. I remember having this with plugin version 2.x too.

Comment: This solution works but you still need to specify the `-noverify` in the test configuration in Android Studio if you want to run them from there.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this

```
 ./gradlew -Dorg.gradle.jvmargs="-ea -noverify" test
```

Comment: I did try it before but still got the java.lang.verifyError.

Comment: I think it needs a `-P` to add as a Gradle property instead of `-D`. As I understand it, `-D` passes arguments to the JVM, whereas `-P` passes it to Gradle. In this instance, you're passing a Gradle property to pass arguments again to JVM.