# How to supply -noverify VM option via command line during gradle build?

Tags: java, android, gradle, junit, jvm-arguments

When running unit tests in Android studio we have to add the -noverify option to the VM options in order to get out unit tests to mock out a third party library with Mockito to pass.

Option I am talking about is reached by Run > Edit Configurations. In a JUnit Run configuration there is a textbox available for VM options (which by default seems to have -ea in it).

I need to run these unit tests on a build server for a CI build. So I need to be able to supply this -noverify CM option on the command line but I do not know how to do this.

Types of things I have tried:

- `gradlew.bat test -Dnoverify`
- `gradlew.bat test -Dverify:none`
- `gradlew.bat test -Dverify=none`
- `gradlew.bat test -noverify`
- Added `org.gradle.jvmargs=-noverify` to the gradle.properties

Answer (score 2):

I was able to add the following to the build.gradle in order to allow CLI runs of units tests to work:

```
testOptions {
   unitTests.all {
      jvmArgs '-noverify'
   }
}
```

Running via Android Studio, however, still requires the `-noverify` options to be supplied via the VM options configuration in the run configuration. Seems like this is because of a Android Studio [Bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/145231226)

[Related Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49320483/android-studio-not-using-gradle-jvmargs-when-running-tests)