# org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [CredDataTmplEntry] ...Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError

Tags: java, hibernate

I have migrated Java 6 to Java 8 and Hibernate 3.2 to 5.3.
During that time I have faced below issue:

**Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target**

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [CredDataTmplEntry]
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:351)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.ClassLoaderAccessImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderAccessImpl.java:62)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.hbm.Helper.reflectedPropertyClass(Helper.java:261)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.hbm.ModelBinder.bindComponent(ModelBinder.java:2584)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.hbm.ModelBinder.bindComponent(ModelBinder.java:2516)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.hbm.ModelBinder.createEmbeddedAttribute(ModelBinder.java:1834)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.hbm.ModelBinder.bindAllCompositeAttributes(ModelBinder.java:2682)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.hbm.ModelBinder.bindComponent(ModelBinder.java:2616)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.hbm.ModelBinder.bindComponent(ModelBinder.java:2516)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.hbm.ModelBinder.createEmbeddedAttribute(ModelBinder.java:1834)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.hbm.ModelBinder.bindAllEntityAttributes(ModelBinder.java:1187)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.hbm.ModelBinder.bindRootEntity(ModelBinder.java:265)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.hbm.ModelBinder.bindEntityHierarchy(ModelBinder.java:185)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.hbm.HbmMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(HbmMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:144)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:218)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:265)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:692)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:770)
        at com.quintron.vx.core.hibernate.AllHWImportTool.doMain(AllHWImportTool.java:240)
        at com.quintron.vx.core.hibernate.AllHWImportTool.main(AllHWImportTool.java:92)
        at com.quintron.vx.core.hibernate.db.admin.ImportData.run(ImportData.java:28)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 20
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/cisco/vx/hwplugins/gw/om/tmpl/CredDataTmplEntry.JiBX_ConfigContentBinding_unmarshal_1_1(Lorg/jibx/runtime/impl/UnmarshallingContext;)Lcom/cisco/vx/hwplugins/gw/om/tmpl/CredDataTmplEntry; @13: ifne
  Reason:
    Expected stackmap frame at this location.
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2b2a b600 7b2a 2a2b b600 9504 829a 0007
    0x0000010: 01a7 001d 2ab4 0002 c000 8ac0 008a 59c7
    0x0000020: 0008 572b b800 8d2b b600 90c0 005e b500
    0x0000030: 022b b600 842a b0

        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:345)
        ... 26 more
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target JDK 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15122890/java-lang-verifyerror-expecting-a-stackmap-frame-at-branch-target-jdk-1-7)

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been resolved when included java 8 compatible jibx jars [jibx-run-1.3.1, 
jibx-bind-1.3.1 and jibx-extras]in the build path.