# OpenJDK11 and JiBX

Tags: spring-mvc, jibx, openjdk-11

Why do I get error below using OpenJDK11, Spring 5.2.3 and JiBX bcel-6.4.1.jar, jibx-bind-1.1.6.jar, jibx-run-1.1.6.jar

Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 20

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'crossSearchSessionFacade' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/gis/spring/spring-business-layer.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mlSearchSessionFacade' while setting bean property 'mlSearchSessionFacade'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mlSearchSessionFacade' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/gis/spring/spring-business-layer.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'configurationSessionFacade' while setting bean property 'configurationSessionFacade'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configurationSessionFacade' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/gis/spring/spring-business-layer.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'gisSaleableUnitsConfigurationService' while setting bean property 'gisSaleableUnitsConfigurationService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gisSaleableUnitsConfigurationService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/gis/spring/spring-business-layer.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jibxSaleableUnitsConfigUnmarshaller' while setting bean property 'jibxSaleableUnitsConfigUnmarshaller'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jibxSaleableUnitsConfigUnmarshaller' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/gis/spring/spring-business-layer.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 20
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/proquest/business/configuration/datamodel/saleableunit/GisSaleableUnitsCollection.JiBX_Proquest_Business_binding_unmarshal_1_0(Lorg/jibx/runtime/impl/UnmarshallingContext;)Lcom/proquest/business/configuration/datamodel/saleableunit/GisSaleableUnitsCollection; @12: ifnonnull
  Reason:
    Expected stackmap frame at this location.
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 2b2a b600 c52a 2a2a b400 3459 c700 0857
    0000010: 2bb8 00ca 2bb8 00ce b500 342b b600 d12a
    0000020: b0

```
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:342)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1699)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1444)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4685)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5146)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:343)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:474)
```

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mlSearchSessionFacade' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/gis/spring/spring-business-layer.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'configurationSessionFacade' while setting bean property 'configurationSessionFacade'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configurationSessionFacade' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/gis/spring/spring-business-layer.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'gisSaleableUnitsConfigurationService' while setting bean property 'gisSaleableUnitsConfigurationService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gisSaleableUnitsConfigurationService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/gis/spring/spring-business-layer.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jibxSaleableUnitsConfigUnmarshaller' while setting bean property 'jibxSaleableUnitsConfigUnmarshaller'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jibxSaleableUnitsConfigUnmarshaller' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/gis/spring/spring-business-layer.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 20
Exception Details:

Comment: Hi, interesting, it may be a bytecode compatibility issue between different JDK versions. Perhaps using `-noverify` might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15122890/java-lang-verifyerror-expecting-a-stackmap-frame-at-branch-target-jdk-1-7

Comment: Never run with `-noverify`, it's terrible advice as it could easily cause the VM to crash. The `VerifyError` you see suggests that something is generated bad class files. You might have to dig into the JiBX issue track to see if is a known issue.

Comment: Has anyone got OpenJDK11 and Spring5.2.3 to work with JiBX?