# Powermock issues with java 7

Tags: java, testng, easymock, powermock

I was running powermock+easymock+testng on java6.
It is working great, but now i have to upgrade to java7.
Everything is falling apart. What should i do to correct it.

I am getting a configuration issue, which is due to calling EasyMock.reset(myObject)

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
org.easymock.internal.ClassExtensionHelper.getControl(ClassExtensionHelper.java:57)
org.easymock.EasyMock.getControl(EasyMock.java:2068)
org.easymock.EasyMock.reset(EasyMock.java:1983)
```

Old set of jars:

```
bsh-2.0b4.jar               easymockclassextension-2.4.jar      jcommander-1.5.jar          rmissl.jar
aopalliance-1.0.jar         cglib-nodep-2.2.jar         guice-2.0.jar               objenesis-1.2.jar           testng-5.14.1.jar
asm-3.0.jar             cobertura.jar               jakarta-oro-2.0.8.jar           powermock-easymock-1.4.6-full.jar   velocity-dep-1.4.jar
asm-tree-3.0.jar            easymock-3.0.jar            javassist-3.13.0-GA.jar         reportng-1.1.2.jar
```

New set of jars:

```
asm-3.0.jar   bsh-2.0b4.jar      cobertura.jar  easymock-3.1.jar       javassist-3.18.0-GA.jar  objenesis-1.2.jar          reportng-1.1.2.jar  snakeyaml-1.6.jar  velocity-dep-1.4.jar
asm-tree-3.0.jar  cglib-nodep-2.2.2.jar  CVS        jakarta-oro-2.0.8.jar  jcommander-1.27.jar  powermock-easymock-1.5.1-full.jar  rmissl.jar          testng-6.8.5.jar
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12493431/977087) issue with Javassist is a problem for Powermock on Java 7

Answer (score 0):

you could try adding this code to your class

```
@ObjectFactory
public IObjectFactory getObjectFactory(){
    return new org.powermock.modules.testng.PowerMockObjectFactory();
}
```

Comment: I am aleady doing that :) . Can you tell me if u have tried these on java7

Comment: on java 7 you must add -XX:-UseSplitVerifier but the error is quite clear when you have to add this to your JVM.. so I'm not 100% sure that this is the cause.