# How to specify separate JVM parameters for junit test classes

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, jvm

As mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7579776/how-to-set-jvm-parameters-for-junit-unit-tests) we can specify JVM parameters for all the test classes in the application.

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.9</version>
<configuration>
    <argLine>-Xmx256M</argLine>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

But how can we specify that **< argLine >** to specific Java class only ?

This is because i'm testing a java.policy file in a test class and I need to pass it as a JVM parameter before run that test class. But I don't want it (policy file) to be considered to other test classes

Comment: I suspect you will need a different module to use different settings for testing.