# Surefire JUnit Testing using Native Libraries

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

We are using Maven in Hudson to run our Java build process and the Surefire plugin to execute JUnit tests however I've run into a problem with the unit tests for one project which requires native dlls.

The error we're seeing is :

> Tests in error: TestFormRegistrationServiceConnection(com.#productidentifierremoved#.test.RegistrationServiceTest): no Authenticator in java.library.path

Where Authenticator is the name of the dll we require.
I found [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195234/pick-up-native-jni-files-in-maven-test-lwjgl) which suggest that the only way to set this is through argLine. We modified our config to this:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.10</version>
        <configuration>
            <forkMode>once</forkMode>
            <argLine>-Djava.library.path=${basedir}\src\main\native\Authenticator\Release</argLine>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

However this still gives the same error and if we include a System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path")); we can see that this is not being added to the path.

Any ideas how we can solve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To add a system property to the JUnit tests, configure the [Maven Surefire Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#systemPropertyVariables) as follows:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <systemPropertyVariables>
          <java.library.path>${project.basedir}/src/main/native/Authenticator/Release</java.library.path>
        </systemPropertyVariables>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Update:

Ok, it seems this property has to be set before the JVM with JUnit tests starts. So I guess that you have problem with the backslashes. Backslashes in the Java property value are used to escape special characters like `\t` (tabulator) or `\r\n` (windows new-line). So try to use this instead of your solution:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <forkMode>once</forkMode>
        <argLine>-Djava.library.path=${project.basedir}/src/main/native/Authenticator/Release</argLine>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```