# Maven: add a folder or jar file into current classpath

Tags: maven-2, jar, classpath

I am using maven-compile plugin to compile classes. Now I would like to add one jar file into the current classpath. That file stays in another location (let's say c:/jars/abc.jar . I prefer to leave this file here). How can I do that?

If I use classpath in the argument:

```
<configuration>
 <compilerArguments>
  <classpath>c:/jars/abc.jar</classpath>
 </compilerArguments>
</configuration>
```

it will not work because it will override the current classpath (that includes all the dependencies)

Comment: Does this jar need to be at exact that location or do you just need a way to include local jars?

Comment: Duplicate of [Maven, how to add additional libs not available in repo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479046/maven-how-to-add-additional-libs-not-available-in-repo), [Maven. What to do with “homeless” jars?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916949/maven-what-to-do-with-homeless-jars), [Local jars are not included in class path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280834/local-jars-are-not-included-in-class-path/3281409#3281409) and many others.

Comment: Did you find a way to add dir? Instead of adding each and individual jar in classpath?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This might have been asked before. See [Can I add jars to maven 2 build classpath without installing them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364114/can-i-add-jars-to-maven-2-build-classpath-without-installing-them#364188)

In a nutshell: include your jar as dependency with system scope. This requires specifying the absolute path to the jar.

See also http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

Comment: I wonder when people will stop suggesting abusing the `system` scope See Brian's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364114/can-i-add-jars-to-maven-2-build-classpath-without-installing-them/764684#764684) in the question you linked to. See also [this previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280834/local-jars-are-not-included-in-class-path/3281409#3281409).

Comment: one more question. If i need to add a folder (contains many .class file) into classpath. how can i do it.

Comment: @Pascal Thivent -- well, it will end when people stop doing nonsense like the bin.zip contained in the org.bytedeco javacv-0.9 project in maven central. If you talk about normal maven behavior, well, as a user I cannot fix the maven upload..... maybe I should complain at maven central.

Comment: this won't work for a folder or dir of jars or classes unfortunately!

Answer (score 4):

The classpath setting of the compiler plugin are two args. Changed it like this and it worked for me:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <compilerArgs>
         <arg>-cp</arg>
         <arg>${cp}:${basedir}/lib/bad.jar</arg>
      </compilerArgs>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
```

I used the gmavenplus-plugin to read the path and create the property 'cp':

```
<plugin>
        <!--
          Use Groovy to read classpath and store into
          file named value of property <cpfile>

          In second step use Groovy to read the contents of
          the file into a new property named <cp>

          In the compiler plugin this is used to create a
          valid classpath
        -->
        <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
        <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.0</version>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <!-- any version of Groovy \>= 1.5.0 should work here -->
            <version>3.0.6</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>read-classpath</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>execute</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>

        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <scripts>
            <script><![CDATA[
                    def file = new File(project.properties.cpfile)
                    /* create a new property named 'cp'*/
                    project.properties.cp = file.getText()
                    println '<<< Retrieving classpath into new property named <cp> >>>'
                    println 'cp = ' + project.properties.cp
                  ]]></script>
          </scripts>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

Answer (score 3):

From [docs](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html) and [example](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/pass-compiler-arguments.html) it is not clear that classpath manipulation is not allowed.

```
<configuration>
 <compilerArgs>
  <arg>classpath=${basedir}/lib/bad.jar</arg>
 </compilerArgs>
</configuration>
```

But see [Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) (also https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/courses/629/jdkdocs/tooldocs/solaris/javac.html)

> -classpath path Specifies the path javac uses to look up classes needed to run javac or being referenced by other classes you are
>   compiling. Overrides the default or the CLASSPATH environment variable
>   if it is set.

Maybe it is possible to get current classpath and extend it,
see [in maven, how output the classpath being used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655010/in-maven-how-output-the-classpath-being-used)

```
    <properties>
      <cpfile>cp.txt</cpfile>
    </properties>

  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>build-classpath</id>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>build-classpath</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <outputFile>${cpfile}</outputFile>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Read file ([Read a file into a Maven property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335221/read-a-file-into-a-maven-property))

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
  <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.4</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>generate-resources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>execute</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <source>
          def file = new File(project.properties.cpfile)
          project.properties.cp = file.getText()
        </source>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

and finally

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <compilerArgs>
         <arg>classpath=${cp}:${basedir}/lib/bad.jar</arg>
      </compilerArgs>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
```

Comment: Surprisingly, there is no easy way to add an external folder of non-maven dependencies to maven's classpath.

None of the approaches here seem to work, they fail with invalid flag: classpath=/pathtojar.jar:/anotherjar.jar

Answer (score 2):

We mixed two of the answers found here to solve a similar problem. Our project needs a JAR only in compile stage, but add a local dependency, using **system** scope, it is unuseful because Maven refuse the artifact publication with an error related to a missing dependency.

The snippets used are the following:

```
  <properties>
    <classpathfile>${basedir}/classpathfile.classpath</classpathfile>
  </properties>
```

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>build-classpath</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>build-classpath</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputFile>${classpathfile}</outputFile>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
        <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>execute</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <source>
                def file = new File(project.properties.classpathfile)
                project.properties.originalClassPath = file.getText()
              </source>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-cp</arg>
            <arg>${originalClassPath}${path.separator}${basedir}/../../../bin/POM_RUNTIME_PLACEHOLDER/ExtraJar.jar</arg>
          </compilerArgs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

Maven is able to compile and successfully deploy the artifacts.
If anyone is interested the full POM is available in GitHub under project [NuReflector](https://github.com/masesgroup/NuReflector), *defaultPOM.template* under src/NuReflector.