# In Maven, how output the classpath being used?

Tags: maven, classpath, war, maven-war-plugin

For my current purposes I have a Maven project which creates a `war` file, and I want to see what actual classpath it is using when creating the `war`. Is there a way to do that in a single command -- without having to compile the entire project?

One idea is to have Maven generate the `target/classpath.properties` file and then stop at that point.

Comment: this should be basic requirement on maven. but i am sure they wont agree.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

To get the classpath all by itself in a file, you can:

```
mvn dependency:build-classpath -Dmdep.outputFile=cp.txt
```

Or add this to the POM.XML:

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>build-classpath</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>build-classpath</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <!-- configure the plugin here -->
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

From: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html

Comment: The `mvn dependency:build-classpath` will by default ouput the classpath for the `test` [dependency scope](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) which includes `system`, `provided`, `compile`, `runtime` and `test`.
 If you want to get the classpath for `compile` or `runtime` scopes. You can use `-Dmdep.includeScope=compile`

Comment: @ecerulm Thank you, that's a very valuable detail. But `-DincludeScope=compile` has worked for me instead of `-Dmdep.includeScope`.

Comment: I've added a complementary [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50368537/1512875) below that allows specifying a desired scope.

Comment: In my use-case I wanted the classpath printed on stdout without having to mess with temporary files. This works: `mvn dependency:build-classpath -Dmdep.includeScope=runtime -Dmdep.outputFile=/dev/fd/4 4>&1 >/dev/null`

Comment: To get it to STDOUT in Linux (and no logging messages) you can use `mvn dependency:build-classpath -Dmdep.outputFile=/dev/stdout -q`

Comment: I got this error when right click mvnw.cmd > open in terminal
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase ".outputFile=cp.txt". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the forma........

Answer (score 23):

This command *outputs* the classpath on Mac and Linux:

```
mvn -q exec:exec -Dexec.executable=echo -Dexec.args="%classpath"
```

Having the result printed and not saved into a file might be useful, for instance, when assigning the result to a variable in a Bash script. This solution runs on Mac and Linux only, but so do Bash shell scripts.

In Windows (e.g. in BAT files), where there is no `echo` executable, you will need something like this (untested):

```
mvn -q exec:exec -Dexec.executable=cmd -Dexec.args="/c echo %classpath"
```

---

Alternatively, you can just execute `java` program with the classpath:

```
mvn -q exec:exec -Dexec.executable=java -Dexec.args="-cp %classpath Main"
```

Or even like that (it will use the correct classpath automatically):

```
mvn -q exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="Main"
```

However, both these alternative approaches suffer from Maven adding its error messages when your program fails.

Comment: How is this better than the accepted answer to this question?

Comment: It outputs the classpath rather than saving it into a file.

Comment: Another advantage of this is that it includes your project's class files as well (`target/classes`), instead of just the dependencies.

Answer (score 17):

or call "mvn -e -X ...." and check the output...

Comment: I don't think that solves the problem because showing errors and debug information doesn't help output the classpath being used.

Comment: the debug information contains the whole classpath for each involved lifecycle plugin (incl. other things as well)

Comment: Thank you sir, I wrote an iteration over your solution, feel free to reuse any of it if you consider it beneficial for the future reader, because right now my answer it's at the bottom and few people will read it (http://stackoverflow.com/a/37551032/2265487)

Answer (score 11):

As [ecerulm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/90580/ecerulm) noted in his comment to [Janik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27451672/1512875), you may want to specify the scope to `dependency:build-classpath`, as classpath output will differ for different scopes (by default `test` is used for some reason). I've ended up with a command like this:

```
mvn -DincludeScope=compile dependency:build-classpath
```

Within the POM, it could be used like this:

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>build-classpath</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>build-classpath</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <includeScope>compile</includeScope>
              <!-- Omit to print on console: -->
              <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/compile-classpath.txt</outputFile>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>build-test-classpath</id>
            <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>build-classpath</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <includeScope>test</includeScope>
              <!-- Omit to print on console: -->
              <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/test-classpath.txt</outputFile>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

This will output 2 versions of classpath, one for main build and the other for tests.

Answer (score 8):

The command `mvn dependency:list` will list the classpath with all the jars used for compilation, runtime and test in the following format:

```
INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:list (default-cli) @ MyProject ---
[INFO]
[INFO] The following files have been resolved:
[INFO]    org.netbeans.api:org-openide-filesystems:jar:RELEASE80:compile
[INFO]    org.netbeans.api:org-netbeans-modules-queries:jar:RELEASE80:compile
[INFO]    org.netbeans.api:org-netbeans-api-progress:jar:RELEASE80:compile
[INFO]    org.netbeans.api:org-openide-dialogs:jar:RELEASE80:compile
[INFO]    org.apache.derby:derby:jar:10.11.1.1:compile
[INFO]    org.netbeans.api:org-openide-windows:jar:RELEASE80:compile
```

The only requirement is that the compilation is finished. 
It doesn't work if the compilation isn't ran.

An other command is The command `mvn dependency:tree`.

Answer (score 6):

Added the missing arg for scope to Janiks answer. Now it is complete. You are welcome.

```
mvn -q exec:exec -Dexec.classpathScope="compile" -Dexec.executable="echo" -Dexec.args="%classpath"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a **single command solution** but **does compile the code**.

```
mvn -e -X -Dmaven.test.skip=true clean compile | grep -o -P '\-classpath .*? ' | awk '{print $2}'
```

- It's based in [Philip Helger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15254/philip-helger)'s previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16655088/2265487) (Thanks by the way)

**Shell script example usage**

```
MAVEN_CLASSPATH=$(mvn -e -X -Dmaven.test.skip=true clean compile | grep -o -P '\-classpath .*? ' | awk '{print $2}')
```

I used a variation of it in a shell script to run a standalone main() (for Hibernate schema generation) this way

```
#/bin/bash

MAVEN_TEST_CLASSPATH=$(mvn -e -X clean package | grep -o -P '\-classpath .*?test.*? ')

java $MAVEN_TEST_CLASSPATH foo.bar.DBSchemaCreate
```

**File output example**

```
mvn -e -X -Dmaven.test.skip=true clean compile | grep -o -P '\-classpath .*? ' | awk '{print $2}' > maven.classpath
```

Comment: With maven 3.3.9, your grep-command does not return anything (unfortunately, I can not see any classpath when running with -e -X). Is there maybe an update to this solution?

Comment: Tested right now on Mint 18 (based on Ubuntu 16.04) and it works :O. Could you provide console responses for `uname -a` and `maven --version` ? On the tested system with successful results the are $ uname -a --> `"Linux ******* 4.4.0-21-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 18 18:33:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux"`. $ mvn --version --> `"Apache Maven 3.3.9; Java version: 1.8.0_111, vendor: Oracle Corporation; OS name: 'linux', version: '4.4.0-21-generic', arch: 'amd64', family: 'unix'`

Comment: Note that if you are not in Linux grep may not be on your system (like in windows) or could behave differently (like on macos for some combination of options). If you are on windows you could try Cygwin or MinGW to have grep, but I don't know if you'll have problems similar to macos, where the Cygwin or MinGW could behave differently than the one used on the Ubuntu 16.04 packages. (if you use windows and find useful the MinGW or Cygwin approach please let me know to update the answer)